# Swift class is not added to autogenerated header for swift in Obj-C project

Tags: objective-c, swift

When I've added Swift class to Objective-C project it was not included to autogenerated header for swift.

My steps was as following:

1. Created single view Objective C project with name "SwiftTest"
2. Build Setting -> Packaging -> Defines Module set to "YES"
3. Product Name (and Product Module Name) was not changes so it was "SwiftTest"
4. Added Swift file SwiftInObjc.swift with single class:

```
    import Foundation
    class SwiftInObjc : NSObject{
        func printHello(){
            println("Hello")
        }
    }
```

5. In ViewController class included header and declared swift object:

```
#import "SwiftTest-Swift.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    SwiftInObjc * swiftObj;
}
```

After that project can't be build because of error:

*Use of undeclared identifier "SwiftInObjc"*

Header file "SwiftTest-Swift.h" has been created in derived data as expected, but it doesn't contain my swift class.

Note: My case is similar to  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24086595/swift-to-objective-c-header-does-not-contain-swift-classes?rq=1)
but my class was subclassed from NSObject so it must be another reason.
(also I've tried pure Swift class:

```
import Foundation

@objc class SwiftInObjc {
    class func newInstance() -> SwiftInObjc {
        return SwiftInObjc()
    }
    func hello() {
        println("hello")
    }
}
```

but it doesn't help, I still have same error)

Comment: I just followed your exact steps and all I got was the expected warning about swiftObj being an unused variable. It compiled and built just fine. I'm using Xcode 6.1; presumably you're also on the current release?

Comment: Issue closed. Matt was right, it was XCode version issue. But he did not post answer so I can't accept it.

Comment: Making sure the swift class inherits from NSObject did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to declare

```
@objc public class SwiftInObjc {}
```