# Calling NSString extension defined in Swift from Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, string, nsstring

I have a a `String` extension which i want to use on `NSString` from `objective c`. As `String` in swift is a `struct` so its not exposed to `objective c`. So in order to call it from `objective c` i defined an `extension` on `NSString` in the same file.

```
public extension NSString {

        func htmlAttributedStringWithFont(font: UIFont, size fontSize: CGFloat = 17.0) -> NSAttributedString? {
            let str = self as String
            return str.htmlAttributedStringWithFont(font: font)
        }

    }



   extension String {

        /// Converts an HTML String to NSAttributedString
        ///
        /// - Returns: NSAttributedString?
        func htmlAttributedString() -> NSAttributedString? {
            guard let data = self.data(using: .utf16, allowLossyConversion: false) else {
                return nil
            }
            guard let html = try? NSMutableAttributedString(
                data: data,
                options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
                documentAttributes: nil) else { return nil }
            return html
        }

        /// returns and NSAttributedString optional from HTML content after applying specific font and size
        ///
        /// - Parameters:
        ///   - font: Font to be applied on the returned string
        ///   - fontSize: Size to be applied on the returned string
        /// - Returns: NSAttributedString?
        func htmlAttributedStringWithFont(font: UIFont, size fontSize: CGFloat = 17.0) -> NSAttributedString? {
            let string = self.appending(String(format: "<style>body{font-family: '%@'; font-size:%fpx;}</style>", font.fontName, fontSize))
            return string.htmlAttributedString()
        }
}
```

The above two extensions are in the same file `String+Extension.swift`. I then tried to call the `htmlAttributedStringWithFont` method from my `objective c` class with `NSString`

```
[str htmlAttributedStringWithFont:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
```

it gives me the following error

```
 No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'htmlAttributedStringWithFont:'
```

Any idea how i can use `String` extension in `Swift` from `Objective c NSString`

Comment: I believe functions with default argument are not exposed to objc. Try writing `@objc func htmlAttributedStringWithFont(font: UIFont, size fontSize: CGFloat = 17.0) -> NSAttributedString?` and check if it returns errors.

Comment: Still the same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27097688/can-objective-c-code-call-swift-extension-on-class

Looks like swift/xcode might generate obj-c headers that need to be imported

Comment: Check if you have a line importing the header `#import "YourProjName-Swift.h"` in the ObjC file. If you really have it, cmd-click on it. You may find the extension method is exposed to ObjC as `htmlAttributedStringWithFontWithFont:size:`. **ObjC name is synthesized from method name and parameter labels.** **No default parameter is supplied when calling the method from ObjC.** You need to use it as `[str  htmlAttributedStringWithFontWithFont:[UIFont systemFontSize] size: 17.0];`.

Comment: Great it worked it was actually `htmlAttributedStringWithFontWithFont ` instead of `htmlAttributedStringWithFont`. Thanks @OOPer

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are working on Swift and Objective-C files in same project, then there is a certain file called **YourProjectName-Swift.h** which is created automatically for you by xCode.
2. Suppose there is a Swift extension you did create or update just now.
3. This should update **YourProjectName-Swift.h** automatically and
   then by importing this header file (**#import "YourProjectName-Swift.h"**) in your Objective-C Class you can
   use Swift code.
4. Just in case, if it doesn't then you can manually
   update this header file.