# Cannot extend UIColor

Tags: swift, uicolor

I tried the steps below to expeand UIColor, but it didn't work.

At first, I added new color set in xcassets,
[image]

and then add UIColor + Extension.swift in my project folder.

```
// UIColor + Extension.swift

import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIColor {

    class var testColor1:UIColor {
      return UIColor(red: 210.0/255.0, green: 105.0/255.0, blue: 130.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }
    class var testColor2: UIColor? { return UIColor(named: "testColor") }

}
```

I want to load custom color in AppDelegate.mm, but got the following error.
[image]

```
animationUIView.backgroundColor = [UIColor testColor1];
```

The code above doesn't work either.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm sorry, but I'm making a project with react native, so I don't know Swift and objective c well.

Comment: You can't mix Objective-C & Swift like that, one line  in each language... So `animationUIView.backgroundColor = [UIColor testColor1];` should be the one, but you might need to make it visible to Objective-C: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27097688/can-objective-c-code-call-swift-class-extensions

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change a background with a custom color you should use :

someView.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "testColor1")

Comment: The `.init(named:)`

Comment: Highlight code section