# How can I import Swift code to Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, import, swift

I have written a library in Swift and I wasn't able to import it to my current project, written in Objective-C.

Are there any ways to import it?

```
#import "SCLAlertView.swift" - 'SCLAlertView.swift' file not found
```

Comment: love this project!

Comment: Answer to this question can be found in the Apple documentation itself:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_swift_into_objective-c


I recommend to read the documentation first before reading all the answers.

Answer (score 525, accepted):

You need to import `ProductName-Swift.h`. Note that it's the product name - the other answers make the mistake of using the class name.

This single file is an autogenerated header that defines Objective-C interfaces for all Swift classes in your project that are either annotated with `@objc` or inherit from `NSObject`.

Considerations:

- If your product name contains spaces, replace them with underscores (e.g. `My Project` becomes `My_Project-Swift.h`)
- If your target is a framework, you need to import `<ProductName/ProductName-Swift.h>`
- Make sure your Swift file is a member of the target

Comment: Note that if you try to use the Swift filename in your import, you will get the error "Expected ';' after top level declarator". in your Swift file after "import Foundation".

Comment: Wow, great catch! Small question: Is there anywhere I can see what that project name is? I tried what you suggested and am still getting errors so I'm worried I might have the project name wrong.

Comment: EDIT: **Note:** for this to work, a project module name MUST be defined. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24064015/2085743

Comment: I just would like to add a note that if your project name has any white space or special character you have to replace them with underscores, like "My App" would be "My_App-Swift.h"

Comment: Hi @Bill how do i use swift library through cocoapod in my objective c project...?

Comment: How does this work in a Framework target, can you just add #import <ProjectName/ProjectName-Swift.h> to the umbrella header?

Comment: Why is this so hard and poorly documented?

Comment: @HardikAmal you can still use, for example, `#import "SCLAlertView-Swift.h"` in Objective-C class, or `@import <SCLAlertView>;`

Comment: @uchuugaka it's not that much hard. First time you can feel a bit pain and then later you would be getting mastery on it.

Comment: I have used `#import "SCLAlertView-Swift.h"` in `.m` and I getting error: `SCLAlertView-Swift.h not found`, I did something wrong?

Comment: @Bill now I have used `#import "Wow_Dictionary-Swift.h"`, where `Wow Dictionary` is my project name. Now I am getting error `Wow_Dictionary-Swift.h not found`. Still something wrong?

Comment: @Aamir Actually, it's the target name, not the project name. Let me update my answer.

Comment: @Bill my project name is same as target name.

Comment: I did this but I get 10 compile errors saying that `No type or protocol UIApplicationDelegate` and similar

Comment: Do you have to import it in your .m file?

Comment: @JohnOttenlips yes

Comment: This auto-generated file is now called `TargetName-Bridging-Header.h` though?

Comment: @lelelo No, that file is the opposite of this one. The bridging header is written by the developer and lets you bring Objective-C and C symbols into your Swift code. The Target-Swift.h file is automatically generated and lets your Objective-C/C code access Swift symbols.

Comment: It's not necessarily the `Target Name`. It is actually `Product Module Name` which you have defined in `Build Settings`. You can have a look at the answer by Sumit Singh

Comment: @Bill sorry to bother you but I have been trying to import the Swift header file but couldn't succeed. The issue is that I have 2 targets in my project. One of the Objective-C files requires to access the Swift header files of both the targets. How would I go about that?

Comment: Hi @Adeel You can create a new header file that #import's `Target1-Swift.h` and `Target2-Swift.h` and import that header into your Objective-C files.

Comment: In the newly created header file it doesn't let me include either of the two. Moreover, if I exclude the objective-c file from one of the targets then the compiler stops complaining about the header file but starts complaining about one of objc class's subclass because that is included in both the targets.

Comment: I found a new way to find the correct generated header file name: ***go to your target -> Build Settings -> Search keywords `Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name`***, bingo!

Comment: **Important note**: You can change the module name for each target to make the name of the swift header the same for each target. Details here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/27411394/956816

Comment: The key is using the `@objc` attribute, wish you could make it in bold, because Apple's documentation doesn't state this properly. Or write it as steps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This phrase "Make sure your Swift file is member of the target" saved my day!

Answer (score 179):

**Here's what to do:**

1. Create a new Project in Objective-C
2. Create a new `.swift` file

   - A popup window will appear and ask *"Would You like to configure an Objective-C bridging Header"*.
   - Choose **Yes**.
3. Click on your **Xcode Project file**
4. Click on **Build Settings**
5. Find the **Search bar** and search for **Defines Module**.
6. Change value to **Yes**.
7. Search **Product Module Name**.
8. Change the value to the name of your project.
9. In App delegate, add the following : `#import "YourProjectName-Swift.h"`

---

**Note:**  Whenever you want to use your Swift file you must be import following line :

`#import "YourProjectName-Swift.h"`

Comment: Changing the value of `Defines module` in `Build settings` to `Yes` is what fixed things for me!

Comment: Embedded Content Contains Swift : YES            USE this also

Comment: good answer but steps 7-8 are not needed in Xcode 7.3.1 and higher

Comment: I have skipped step NO. 6  even it is working for me... is this step really needed.??? my define module is set to NO

Comment: Not works for me in `xcode 8.3.2`. Works in previous versions

Comment: @jose920405 let me know what step you are following because the same steps for same Xcode version is working for me.

Comment: Just want to add that `YourProjectName` in `#import "YourProjectName-Swift.h"` will be the name of project from step 8. Useful if your project name contains special characters and you are not sure how exactly you should format it.

Comment: This is exactly *not* answering OPs question.

Answer (score 171):

Instructions from the Apple website:

> To import Swift code into Objective-C from the same framework
>
> Under **Build Settings**, in **Packaging**, make sure the **Defines Module**
>   setting for that framework target is set to **Yes**. Import the Swift code
>   from that framework target into any Objective-C .m file within that
>   framework target using this syntax and substituting the appropriate
>   names:
>
> **#import "ProductName-Swift.h"**

**Revision:**

You can only import **"ProductName-Swift.h"** in .m files.

> The Swift files in your target will be visible in Objective-C .m files
>   containing this import statement.
>
> To avoid cyclical references, don’t import Swift into an Objective-C
>   header file. Instead, you can forward declare a Swift class to use it
>   in an Objective-C header. Note that you cannot subclass a Swift class
>   in Objective-C.

[image]

Comment: Only import "ProductName-Swift.h" in .m files helped me. Adding same in .pch file was giving "Cannot find protocol declaration for 'CLLocationManagerDelegate'; did you mean 'NSLayoutManagerDelegate'?"

Comment: @AJit it doesn't directly, the documentation says that. The easiest way is to create an Objective-C class that translates in a format that Objective-C++ understands. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH2-ID0

Comment: Note that you have to derive from `NSObject` !!! you can't just straight up declare a `class Blah`  in swift and have it work. it needs to be `class Blah : NSObject`

Comment: Worth reading this answer for some cases:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26328034/importing-project-swift-h-into-a-objective-c-class-file-not-found

Depending on what you are doing:

#import <ProductName/ProductModuleName-Swift.h>
#import <ProductModuleName-Swift.h>
#import <NewTestApp/NewTestApp-Swift.h>

Comment: What if you want import a Swift extension?

Comment: In my case `"ProductName-Swift.h"` works perfect in `xcode 7.3` but now works in `xcode 8.3.2`

Comment: @AlejandroIván I have UIView swift class will it work ? I am not able to import swift into objective c

Comment: The missing module was my issue for a test project. Furthermore, if your project name starts with a numerical, (eg, 1234.xcodeproj), it too will replace the first offending character with _, thus your module name will default to "_234" and thus your include will look like "_234-Swift.h".

Comment: "Note that you cannot subclass a Swift class in Objective-C." Thank you for including this, it saved me from going crazy.

Comment: will this work for structs.  I dont believe that they can be derived from NSObject so I am guessing not.  I am trying to do this with a constants class

Answer (score 48):

If you're using Cocoapods and trying to use a Swift pod in an ObjC project you can simply do the following:

> `@import <FrameworkName>;`

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! you saved my day.

Comment: This works like a charm if we installed swift-made library through Cocoapods. Upvoted !!!

Answer (score 25):

Go to build settings in your project file and search for **"Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name**. *The value of that property is the name that you should include.*

If your "Product Module Name" property (the one that the above property depends on by default) varies depending on whether you compile for test/debug/release/etc (like it does in my case), then make this property independent of that variation by setting a custom name.

Answer (score 19):

Importing `Swift` file inside `Objective-c` can cause this error, if it doesn't `import` properly.

**NOTE: You don't have to import Swift files externally, you just have to import one file which takes care of swift files.**

When you **Created/Copied Swift file** inside **Objective-C project**. It would've created a bridging header automatically.

Check `Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name` at `Targets -> Build Settings`.

[image]

Based on above, I will import `KJExpandable-Swift.h` as it is.

Your's will be `TargetName-Swift.h`, Where `TargetName` differs based on your project name or another target your might have added and running on it.

As below my target is `KJExpandable`, so it's `KJExpandable-Swift.h`
[image]

Answer (score 16):

**First Step:-**

Select Project Target -> Build Setting -> Search('Define') -> **Define Module** 
update value **No** to **Yes**

"Defines Module": **YES**.

"Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries" : **YES**.

"Install Objective-C Compatibility Header" : **YES**.

[image]

**Second Step:-**

Add Swift file Class in Objective C ".h" File as below

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class TestViewController(Swift File);

@interface TestViewController(Objective C File) : UIViewController

@end
```

Import 'ProjectName(Your Project Name)-Swift.h' in Objective C ".m" file

```
//TestViewController.m 
#import "TestViewController.h"

/*import ProjectName-Swift.h file to access Swift file here*/

#import "ProjectName-Swift.h"
```

Comment: The forward declaration (@class) of the class is a very good point! Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

If you have a project created in Swift 4 and then added Objective-C files, do it like this:

```
@objcMembers
public class MyModel: NSObject {
    var someFlag = false         
    func doSomething() {         
        print("doing something")
    }
}
```

Reference: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/objc-warnings-upgrading-to-swift-4/

Comment: In my code, after I updated it to Swift 4.2 from swift 3. It's not working

Comment: what error are you getting? I have used above code in Swift4.2 and its working fine.

Comment: Ok that’s great.

Answer (score 12):

There's one caveat if you're importing Swift code into your Objective-C files *within the same* framework. You have to do it with specifying the framework name and angle brackets:

`#import <MyFramework/MyFramework-Swift.h>`

`MyFramework` here is the "Product Module Name" build setting (`PRODUCT_NAME = MyFramework`).

Simply adding `#import "MyFramework-Swift.h"` won't work. If you check the built products directory (before such an `#import` is added, so you've had at least one successful build with some Swift code in the target), then you should still see the file `MyFramework-Swift.h` in the `Headers` directory.

Answer (score 7):

Be careful with dashes and underscores, they can be mixed up and your Project Name and Target name won't be the same as SWIFT_MODULE_NAME.

[image: Dashes and underscores]

Answer (score 5):

Checkout the pre-release notes about Swift and Objective C in the same project

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_75

You should be importing

```
#import "SCLAlertView-Swift.h"
```

Comment: Showed me this error: 'SCLAlertView-Swift.h' file not found.

Comment: Needs to be the project name, not the filename - see my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation link. That was useful for reference.

Comment: To quote from the provided link: `The name of this header is your product module name followed by adding "-Swift.h".` So it's not the class name as you wrote, but the name of your product module and that takes care of importing all swift files, not just a specific one

Answer (score 4):

Search for **"Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name"** in the Build Settings of the target you're trying to build (let's say it's `MyApp-Swift.h`), and import the value of this setting (`#import "MyApp-Swift.h"`) in the source file where you're trying to access your Swift APIs.

The default value for this field is `$(SWIFT_MODULE_NAME)-Swift.h`. You can see it if you double-click in the value field of the "Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name" setting.

Also, if you have dashes in your module name (let's say it's `My-App`), then in the `$(SWIFT_MODULE_NAME)` all dashes will be replaced with underscores. So then you'll have to add `#import "My_App-Swift.h"`.

Comment: Better than the approved. The dashes wasted 20 min I'll never get back haha.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use **Swift** file into **Objective-C** class, so from Xcode 8 onwards you can follow below steps:

If you have created the project in Objective-C:

1. Create new Swift file
2. Xcode will automatically prompt for **Bridge-Header file**
3. Generate it
4. Import "ProjectName-Swift.h" in your Objective-C controller (import in implementation not in interface) (if your project has space in between name so use underscore "Project_Name-Swift.h")
5. You will be able to access your Objective-C class in Swift.

Compile it and if it will generate linker error like: compiled with newer version of Swift language (3.0) than previous files (2.0) for architecture x86_64 or armv 7

Make one more change in your

6. Xcode -> Project -> Target -> Build Settings -> Use Legacy Swift Language Version -> Yes

Build and Run.

Comment: i am not getting this option of use legacy swift language version

Answer (score 1):

```
#import <TargetName-Swift.h>
```

you will see when you enter from keyboard #import < and after automaticly Xcode will advice to you.

Answer (score 0):

only some tips about syntax, about Xcode everything has been said

1. you cannot import 'pure" functions, only classes, even if marked "public", so:

   public func f1(){
   print("f1");
   }

will NOT be called in ANY way.

2. If You write classes., add inheritance from NSObject, other will NOT be usable.
3. if it inherits from NSObject, as below:

   class Utils : NSObject{

   static func aaa()->String{
   return "AAA"
   }

   @objc static func bbb()->String{
   return "BBB"
   }

   @objc private static func ccc()->String{
   return "CCC"
   }

   }

in OBJC:

aaa() NOT called: "No known class method for selector 'aaa'"

**bbb() ok**

ccc() NOT called: "No known class method for selector 'aaa'"

Answer (score -2):

Find the .PCH file inside the project. and then add  `#import "YourProjectName-Swift.h"` This will import the class headers. So that you don't have to import into specific file.

```
#ifndef __IPHONE_3_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iPhone SDK 3.0 and later."
#endif


#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "YourProjectName-Swift.h"
#endif
```