# "Expected ';' after top level declarator" under Swift

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I'm trying to set all my colours in one Swift file that can be used throughout my application.

The following code below results in...

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class DotColors {

let tsblueColor = UIColor(red:58/255.0, green: 125/255.0, blue: 208/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

}
```

... **Expected ';' after top level declarator**

Comment: Is it a iOS Project? So does it use the correct xcrun command?

Comment: Yes, universal iOS 8 SDK project - run from the default built settings.

Comment: How do you try accessing it? Cause you can check it with a iOS Playground that it is totally valid: class DotColors {
    
    let tsblueColor = UIColor(red:58/255.0, green: 125/255.0, blue: 208/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    
}

var color = DotColors()
color.tsblueColor

Comment: Checked in Playground and it seems to bring up the same error.

Comment: 1) What line is that error on? 2) Humour me, will you? Copy the code *from here on Stack Overflow* into a new Playground, and see if it suffers from the same problem? I'm wondering if you've got a (virtually-) invisible Xcode placeholder sitting in your source code, or some other character that you can't see.

Comment: @MattGibson 1) The error is on line of "import Foundation" 2) Entering this exact code into a brand new Playground delivers the error of "No such module 'UIKit' on the line of "import UIKit"

Comment: @Damian That will be because you've created an OS X playground, not an iOS playground. Create the right one, or change the existing playground type using the File Inspector. (UIKit is unavailable in OS X playgrounds, just as Cocoa is unavailable in iOS playgrounds)

Comment: @MattGibson Ah whoops, haven't used Playgrounds before. Changed the platform and the code runs without error. Assuming their might be an issue with my iOS project?

Comment: I'm thinking that there may just be some dodgy invisible character in your original file, or something like that. Try pasting the working code from the playground into the project that's not working, or deleting and re-typing it a line at a time, or something similar.

Comment: #import "ProjectName-Swift.h" to import from SDK.

Answer (score 8):

The same error occurred to me after I've added the **first** swift file to my objc project.
That's how I fixed it:

1. Make sure you use an "iOS Source" file (not "OS X Source") when you've added the file.
2. Don't import the swift file in your objc file like: `#import "ExampleFile.swift"` but use `#import "ProjectName-Swift.h"`
3. Make sure you use `@objc` statements in your swift code that you want to import to objc

---

These are the links that were helpful:

- [apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html)
- [how-to-import-swift-code-to-objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102104/how-to-import-swift-code-to-objective-c)

Comment: Thanks, @lukas_o To Understand 2nd and 3rd point I took 3 hours. shame on me :(

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to import UIKit.

```
import UIKit
```

You can try this,

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class DotColors {

  let tsblueColor = UIColor(red:58/255.0, green: 125/255.0, blue: 208/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

}
```

Comment: I have attempted to add UIKit, although I get a further error "Expected ';' after top level declarator".

Comment: update your code snippet in question so, I can check.

Comment: Has there been any further information on this? Did you solve the problem? If so please post your solution and close the question as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting

```
import UIKit
```

In the top.  Think that will solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

I got this error, persisting even once i made the appropriate code changes, after accidentally selecting an OS X Source Cocoa Class in the new file prompt, instead of an iOS Source Cocoa Touch Class.

Try creating a new swift file that you're sure is kicked off as iOS.