# How to: Ignore autogenerated "<project>-Swift.h" warnings

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, warnings

I have a project with both, Swift and Objective-C code.
I have no warnings except one file with the project name and then the suffix *-Swift.h*, it is the auto generated header from the Swift files.

This file is not in my project navigator nor in the folder of the project in the Finder. I can not find it in the Build Phases to add `-fno-objc-arc`.

Changing the file and adding code to suppress the warning will be deleted the next time I build the app.

At the top of the file is the line

```
// Generated by Swift version 1.0 (swift-600.0.47.8)
```

How can I get rid of this warning without disabling the helpful warnings for the other files in my project?

---

Warning exmaples:

> Default property attribute 'assign' not appropriate for non-GC object
>
> No 'assign', 'retain', or 'copy' attribute is specified - 'assign' is assumed

---

#### Swift code:

```
@objc class ... {
    internal var label: Identifier
}
```

#### Autogenerated code (both warning types):

```
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC12...")
@interface ...
@property (nonatomic) Identifier * label; // warnings here
@end
```

Comment: What warnings do you get that you want to suppress? (And adding -fno-objc-arc to a .h file does not make sense because they are not compiled on its own, they are included by .m or other source files.)

Comment: @MartinR Added the warning types to the description

Comment: Perhaps you can give a (minimal) example of Swift code, the corresponding bridged code and the exact locations of the warnings.

Comment: I have difficulties to reproduce the issue. What is `Identifier`? Do you have non-default warning flags set, like -Weverything?

Comment: @MartinR Hmm you are right, it only shows warning on custom Swift types (like `Identifier`). Yes some non-default warnings are activated. If I change `Identifier` to `NSInteger` there is no warning, when I use `NSString` there is `copy` as property attribute and therefore also no warning. Maybe I have to say it should be retain/strong, but how in Swift.

Comment: I am still waiting for a minimal *self-contained* example ...

Comment: I'm also having this problem.. Any progress?

Comment: @zavié Nope sorry, I could not reproduce the error in a very small testing project. If you could, that would be great.

Comment: I had this issue the same. It turns out that I have an old objective-c class which I set -fno-objc-arc compiler flag to and this objective-c class imports <project>-swift.h which causes this warning very reasonably. Eventually I made the objective-c class to support ARC and the warning is gone.

Comment: @BerbyHuang That is what I have too. So the warning is maybe caused only by Objective-C classes with `-fno-objc-arc` and code special to manual reference counting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comment on the original question solved it for me. Once I converted the non-ARC Objective-C classes that were importing the generated Swift.h file to ARC the warnings went away.

> I had this issue the same. It turns out that I have an old objective-c
>   class which I set -fno-objc-arc compiler flag to and this objective-c
>   class imports -swift.h which causes this warning very
>   reasonably. Eventually I made the objective-c class to support ARC and
>   the warning is gone. –  Berby Huang Sep 19 '14 at 5:18

Answer (score 2):

You need to import UIKit in the file that is throwing the error.

Swift:

```
import UIKit
```

Obj C:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

Also, take a look at my previous post:
[How to import Swift code to Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102104/how-to-import-swift-code-to-objective-c/26873548#26873548)

Given the above, try to disable "Defines Module", clean your project, and re-enable "Defines Module". Hope this helps.