# Project-Swift.h in Project-Prefix.pch casuse no 'assign', 'retain', or 'copy' attribute is specified - 'assign' is assumed warning

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a project that is written in Objective-C and I am trying to add Swift to it. I have read several places that I can import my `Project-Swift.h` header in my `Project-Prefix.pch`. This works but I get a bunch of `no 'assign', 'retain', or 'copy' attribute is specified - 'assign' is assumed` warnings.

Am I doing something wrong or is it not possible to import the `Project-Swift.h` header in `Project-Prefix.pch`?

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    #import "Project-Swift.h"
#endif
```

Comment: Possibly similar or related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25451539/how-to-ignore-autogenerated-project-swift-h-warnings?rq=1.

Comment: Are any of the Objective-C files compiled *without* ARC ?