# Objective C to Swift header file with multiple targets

Tags: objective-c, swift, header-files, target

I'm successfully calling my Swift classes from Objective C (for target 'MyApp') via the import statement:

```
#import "MyApp-Swift.h"
```

I've now created a new target called "MyAppLite"

When I compile the new target, I get errors because "MyApp-Swift.h" is required by the code, but the compiler is creating "MyAppLite-Swift.h"

So, I need to create a conditional Swift/ObjC header `#import` for the target I'm compiling against.

How can this be done, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

It is also possible to set the `Product Module Name` setting in `Build Settings` to be the same across your modules (I set it to `$(PROJECT_NAME)`), so that the `<project>-Swift.h` file that is generated has the same name across all modules. This eliminates the need for adding/checking preprocessor macros.

Comment: When you create your first Swift-file in your project, xcode will ask you to add the bridging header to the project. In my case it only added the needed config to the _first_ build target. So I also needed to fix the other build targets by configuring the `Objective-C Bridging Header`

Comment: I found that this caused issues in the build process, and that when switching between them, I needed to clean the build folder. I believe that because they all share the same project name, they all build to the same folder.

Comment: I"m not sure, but my feeling is that messing with the `Product Module Name` will affect something later on, probably when submitting to the App Store ;)... changing the `Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name` as described in the other answer has no implications.

Comment: @Yar Just saw your comment. That was my feeling initially but the app has been in the App Store for a while and it hasn't been an issue. But if I was using the latest version of Xcode, I'd use Mike Fay's solution tbh. This answer was made before `SWIFT_MODULE_NAME` was available.

Comment: God bless you! Using same module name across all my targets save me from crappy issue with custom swift class in mixed Swift/ObjC project which happens only in release build!!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @boraseoksoon This answer is a little dated. I'd go with the answer by Mike Fay for recent XCode versions

Comment: This is not really the correct answer, I would go with the second most upvoted answer

Answer (score 69):

The best way I've found to address this issue is in your Xcode shared project settings. You can search for the following setting:

**Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name***

If you set that value to a common header name, such as "MyProject-Swift.h", it will be applied to each of your targets and you can safely use the import declaration in any of your Objective-C files. This allows you to continue using unique product module names for each target, if needed.

I've tested this in Xcode Version 6.4 (6E35b).

*Note: This will appear under your Swift compiler settings, which are only visible if you have Swift source files added to your project. Additionally, if a target doesn't have any Swift source associated with it, the Swift compiler options will not be visible for that target's build settings.

Good luck!

Comment: This is the best solution IMO.

Comment: The original value of this is `$(SWIFT_MODULE_NAME)-Swift.h`... so while this answer is awesome, I'd *love* to know how to adjust the `SWIFT_MODULE_NAME` for the module.

Comment: While I'm here, I'd recommend using some obvious name to reduce confusion, e.g., `MidiDesignerAllTargets-Swift.h` Thanks for this great answer, it's a *great* find.

Comment: This is the best solution if you are using Xcode 7+.

Comment: It is definitely still available in Version 8.3.3 (8E3004b).

Comment: @AntonTropashko You will need to select show/filter `All` and not `Basic` to see it.

Answer (score 52):

Previous answers have some problems if you decide to rename your targets or project, or use `SWIFT_MODULE_NAME` as intended.

The most universal solution is to change `SWIFT_OBJC_INTERFACE_HEADER_NAME` (“Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name”) under Project's, not Targets, Build Settings, to:

- `$(PROJECT_NAME)-Swift.h` — one per project;
- `$(SWIFT_MODULE_NAME)-Swift.h` — one per module (default value).

[image]

Comment: the cleanest of all solutions.Xcode 8.3.3, Swift 3, make sure the common/shared swift files belong to each target, all works after this.

Comment: How to handle "$(PROJECT_NAME)-Swift.h file not found" error like warnings?

Comment: This should be accepted Answer as it shows some more details though @C0D3LIC1OU5 's answer was good enought

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 6):

Well, the only way I can fix is to...

```
#ifdef IS_LITE
#import "MyApp_Lite-Swift.h"
#else
#import "MyApp-Swift.h"
#endif
```

Note that if there's any 'illegal' chars in my Product Module Name, they need to be replaced with underscores.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This worked for me, as the accepted answer caused build issues when switching between targets.

Comment: what's IS_LITE?

Answer (score 5):

I put the appropriate #import <project>-Swift.h statement in a prefix header file (<project>-Prefix.pch) defined/added for each build (target/scheme).

Comment: This has the advantage of making it more convenient to use Swift classes in Objective-C, and more consistency between the Swift experience, where headers do not need to be explicitly imported, and the Objective-C experience.

Answer (score 1):

> pickture will tell you all

1. second targets name xxx and xxx-ih

[image]

2. select first target tap `build setting` -> find `Objective-C Bridging Header` set `xxx-bridging-Header.h` and `Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name` set `xxx-Swift.h`
   [image]
3. select second target and same step `2`
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

The only working way is the following : 
1- from first target (which has a working bridging) **Build Setting** select **Objective C Bridging Header** 
2- Copy **Objective C Bridging Header** 
3- open the other target **Build Setting**
4- Paste it
5- change the header file to your new header file (i.e target B.h)

(now you have this option for two target)