# Swift generated header with multiple targets

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am having trouble generating the swift header needed to use Swift classes from ObjC, when there are multiple targets with common code.

I created two targets `My OSX App` and `My iOS App`. These targets share common code where an ObjC class is calling a Swift class.

As described in [Swift and ObjC in the same project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) I can add `#import "My_iOS_App-Swift.h"` to my ObjC class and compile it from the `My iOS App` target.

However, this doesn't compile from the `My OSX App` target, as the include needs to match the module name. It is looking for `#import "My_OSX_App-Swift.h"`but the common code does not use that include.

What is the correct way to mix/match Swift/ObjC in code that is shared between multiple targets? I could manually change every target to use a common `MyApp-Swift.h`, but that doesn't feel right and may cause other problems.

Comment: Use a pod or a module for code that's not platform specific.  It shouldn't by `My_iOS_App-Swift.h` or `MyApp-Swift.h`.  It should by `MyLibrary-Swift.h`

Comment: Yes, that makes sense however I inherited this project and it wasn't set up that way. Can I manually change the name of the generated -Swift.h so each target uses the same one without causing problems? Restructuring the projects to use a library may be too much change at the moment. (I would like to accept your answer but can't from a comment)

Answer (score 5):

Set the *Product Module Name* setting in Build Settings to be the same across your modules

For example: $(PROJECT_NAME)

Or use fixed names if you have watch extensions for different targets like: Main_App and Watchkit

This causes the ###-Swift.h file that is generated has the same name across all modules. This also eliminates the need for adding/checking preprocessor micros.

From: [Objective C to Swift header file with multiple targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26262029/objective-c-to-swift-header-file-with-multiple-targets)

Comment: This seemed really dangerous to me...  but after trying to ifdef my way around things, i tried this and got past my previous errors! Great suggestion.