# Single -swift.h shared by multiple targets

Tags: swift, xcode

how do I include a single -swift.h in a file shared by multiple targets in xcode?

I want to include "PROJECTNAME-Swift.h" once
rather than have a sea of

```
#if SOMETHING_SPECIFIC_FOR_TARGET_1
#import "Target1-Swift.h"
#elsif SOMETHING_SPECIFIC_FOR_TARGET_2
#import "Target2-Swift.h"
...
```

Comment: Could you please include some code that illustrates the problem

Comment: yes, the only issue is the helpful answer in there is not an accepted one but is burried a tad bit below.

Comment: That doesn’t make this one not be a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This
[Objective C to Swift header file with multiple targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26262029/objective-c-to-swift-header-file-with-multiple-targets/27411394#27411394)

helped.

once you will have added custom user defined setting
SWIFT_MODULE_NAME as Foo for each and every target you can
swiftly import Foo-Swift.h instead of a gazillion of target specific TargetX-Swift.h