# Xcode 7 compile error, can't import Swift class in Objective-C files

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I got a compile error with my old project, it used Objective-C and Swift 1.2, and Xcode will auto generate a file named "PROJECTNAME-Swift.h", I import this file in my AppDelegate. But when I open the project with Xcode 7, the import report an error. I have used the convert to the lastest Swift syntax.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of this :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102104/how-to-import-swift-code-to-objective-c

Comment: Hey I am also facing same issue , I bridged swift files in objective c project which was working fine in xcode6.4 but as soon as I run it xcode7 it shows "cannot find protocols declaration for PROTOCOL_NAME" or "no visible @Interface for FILE_NAME declares the selector METHOD_NAME".
Yet I couldn't find any solution for it

Comment: the same problem as me. Finally I use the Xcode 6.4 for work.

Answer (score 1):

just try to change this

> Under **Build Settings**, in **Packaging**, make sure the **Defines Module** setting for that framework target is set to **Yes**.

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to header search path and delete all the code from there after that add new by pressing + icon and from xcode drag and drop the path of your **ProjectName-Bridging-Header** and try
2. Have you delete **derived data** ? if not then delete derived data and then clean+build your app