# Is there any 3rd party library available in iOS(Objc) for `textinputlayout` like android

Tags: ios, objective-c, textinputlayout

I am search a Library in iOS (Objc) for `textinputLayout` like android has.

here is the video url for more clarity,
https://youtu.be/YnQHb0fNtF8

Can anyone please tell if there is any 3rd party library available or do I need to write my own code with the help of animations.

Comment: You can use your custom view with textfield validation on didEndEditing delegate **or** you can find similar library with https://github.com/enisgayretli/EGFloatingTextField

Comment: @mrunalthanki thanks, this is what I was asking. your please post your ans I will upvote

Comment: @Bhupesh EGFloatingTextField  is in swift language .not in objective c

Comment: you can use swift libraries in your objective-c code @Bhumika

Comment: @Bhumika, Yes I saw its in swift

Comment: @Bhupesh As an off-site resource request, your question is blatantly off-topic.

Comment: how you got 1811 rep?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use your custom view with textfield validation on didEndEditing delegate and validate and make your custom design for your validations .
**or** 
you can find similar library with

1. https://github.com/enisgayretli/EGFloatingTextField (swift)
2. https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/swiftyform (swift)

Comment: I checked EGFloatingTextField its in swift, I am looking for Obj-C

Comment: @Bhupesh you can find solution for this on this link : https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: you can also find relative answers on : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102104/how-to-import-swift-code-to-objective-c

Comment: you can find here tutorial for using swift code in your objective c with descriptive steps with screenshots : https://medium.com/ios-apprentice/using-swift-in-objective-c-projects-f7e7a09f8be

Comment: One more suggestion [JVFloatLabeledTextField](https://github.com/jverdi/JVFloatLabeledTextField) , implemented in Objective-C