# Execute swift code in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios9

When I execute Swift methods in Objective-C the code which is inside of that method does not run.

For example: I want to open a new view or enable a button.

#### Objective-C code:

```
Principal *myClass = [[Principal alloc] init];
[myClass getData];
```

#### Swift code:

```
func getData() {
    let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MenuViewController") as UIViewController
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
}
```

Comment: You need to post code showing what your trying to do

Comment: I post some code yet. @SimonMcLoughlin

Comment: I post some code yet. @prince

Comment: Similar question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102104/how-to-import-swift-code-to-objective-c?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you use the @objc keyword to tag your Swift classes so they’re available to your ObjC ones.

```
import Foundation

@objc class TestClass {
class func new() -> TestClass {
    return TestClass()
}

func testFunction() {
    println("This function works")
}
}
```

And here’s the Objective-C client:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "TestProject-Swift.h"
@implementation AppDelegate
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    TestClass *instance = [TestClass new];
    [instance testFunction];
    return YES;
}
@end
```

The secret here is to import the name of the target in this case “TestProject” with the “-Swift.h” extension. Xcode builds this for you and hides it behind the scenes in the derived data. For the above example, mine was left at: DerivedData/TestProject-aqpeqeuqusyzdtcqddjdixoppyqn/Build/Intermediates/TestProject.build/Debug-iphoneos/TestProject.build/DerivedSources/TestProject-Swift.h

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a header (.h file) into your Project and import all classes you needed.

Your header file looks like.

```
#ifndef ProjectName_Bridging_Header_h
#define ProjectName_Bridging_Header_h

#import "Principal.h"
```

Afer that in your Build Settings, you need to be set the header file name into `Objective-C Bridging Header`

Like this. [image]

Comment: Isn't that for running Objective-C **inside** Swift? He wants to run Swift inside Objective-C (exactly the opposite), or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, I want call Swift function in Objective-C.

Comment: Make sure you use the @objc keyword to tag your Swift classes so they’re available to your ObjC ones.