# Unable to call swift function in objective C. Getting error interface decleration for NSObject

Tags: objective-c, swift

Am getting error while calling swift function in objective c file.
I have created "-Swift.h" file.

I have created ".swift" file. My code here is

```
import Foundation
@objc class className : NSObject {
@objc func someFunc(sender: AnyObject) {
//Some code
}
}
```

I have created "-Swift.h" header file. My code here is

```
#ifndef ProjectName_Swift_h
#define ProjectName_Swift_h
#endif /* ProjectName_Swift_h */
@class className;
@interface className : NSObject
-(void)someFunc;
@end
```

In my objective C ".m" file am calling the swift function.

```
#import "XXX-Swift.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    className *obj = [[className alloc]init];
    [obj someFunc];
}
```

Now am getting error in "XXX-Swift.h" file.

ERROR: Cannot find interface declaration for 'NSObject', super class for 'className'.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found difference between manually creating -Bridging-header file and automatically Xcode generated -Bridging-header file. I have deleted the -Swift.h file and manually created -Bridging-header file. Added -Bridging-header(Xcode generated one) file. It automatically created -Swift.h file after successful build of project.

Comment: Casey's answer was correct.  Why write this and then give yourself the correct answer??? -1

Comment: Ya you are right but the way i worked out is this and am done with this success fully.

Answer (score 3):

delete the file you created ending in `-Swift.h`, that file is auto-generated by Xcode.

you can view the Xcode generated version (after a successful build) if you command click `#import "XXX-Swift.h"`

if you go into your build settings and search for `SWIFT_OBJC_INTERFACE_HEADER_NAME` you can see the file name.

Comment: I have done this but am getting errors. In ".swift" file Error: "Expected ';' top level declaration and Unknown type name 'import' ".

Comment: the code in your .swift file is missing the final ```}```

Comment: did this answer your question? what error are you getting now?

Comment: this helped me. But not completely. i found the solution by trial and error. finally its done.

Answer (score 0):

you have to created Bridging header file and import you swift file there.

Use this link, it will help you

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: Check this link, you get you solution
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102104/how-to-import-swift-code-to-objective-c

Comment: For accessing swift code in objective c i think no need to create bridging header.h. I just created -swift.h even though i tried am getting the same error

Comment: Check out apple documentation , that i given a link above, it will solve your problem.