# Cropping image same as updated version of Instagram

Tags: ios, instagram, crop, zooming

I want to crop image in my application same as updated Instagram.
I have create one demo for it. 
But i got 1 issue in this demo.
Issue is that, when i zoomIn image and then try to zoom out little bit that time UIImageview zooming out full. Please check demo u got my point which i try to explain
**This is my demo link 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw367uJS6w22OTNwTmdCNW5Ta3M/view?usp=sharing**

Comment: Make a appropriate gif and share it within the question and post relevant code.. External links might not work in future and the question would then be not helpful to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can this library if you want instagram like camera and imagepicker

https://github.com/ytakzk/Fusuma

Comment: This code is in  Swift language.  I want Objective-c.

Comment: you can use swift library in objective c project

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102104/how-to-import-swift-code-to-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

In `VPImageCropperViewController` file You will find a method

```
- (void) pinchView:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinchGestureRecognizer you have to change in that code to work zoom out functionality.

- (void) pinchView:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinchGestureRecognizer
{
    UIView *view = self.showImgView;
    if (pinchGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || pinchGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(view.transform, pinchGestureRecognizer.scale, pinchGestureRecognizer.scale);
        //pinchGestureRecognizer.scale = 1;
                self.showImgView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
         NSLog(@"%f",pinchGestureRecognizer.scale);
//        pinchGestureRecognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(pinchGestureRecognizer.view.transform, pinchGestureRecognizer.scale, pinchGestureRecognizer.scale);
//        pinchGestureRecognizer.scale = 1;
    }
    else if (pinchGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

        NSLog(@"original image size%f",self.originalImage.size.width);
        NSLog(@"latestFrame image size%f",self.latestFrame.size.width);
//        NSLog(@"original image size%f",self.originalImage.size.width);
//        NSLog(@"original image size%f",self.originalImage.size.width);

      /*  if(pinchGestureRecognizer.scale <= 1.0)
        {

            // small
            CGRect newFrame = self.showImgView.frame;
            UIImage *img=[self imageWithImage:self.originalImage scaledToSize:self.cropFrame.size];
            newFrame = [self handleScaleOverflow:CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height)];
            newFrame = [self handleBorderOverflow:CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height)];
            newFrame = [self handleScaleOverflow:newFrame];
            newFrame = [self handleBorderOverflow:newFrame];
            [UIView animateWithDuration:BOUNDCE_DURATION animations:^{
                self.showImgView.frame = newFrame;
                self.latestFrame = newFrame;
                self.showImgView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

            }];
        }*/


       /* if(pinchGestureRecognizer.scale > 1.0)
        {*/
            // big
            CGRect newFrame = self.showImgView.frame;
            newFrame = [self handleScaleOverflow:newFrame];
            newFrame = [self handleBorderOverflow:newFrame];
            [UIView animateWithDuration:BOUNDCE_DURATION animations:^{
                self.showImgView.frame = newFrame;
                self.latestFrame = newFrame;
            }];
        //}

    }
}
```

May be it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Do changes in VPImageCropperViewController.m file

```
// pinch gesture handler
    - (void) pinchView:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinchGestureRecognizer
    {
        UIView *view = self.showImgView;

        if (pinchGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || pinchGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

            view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(view.transform, pinchGestureRecognizer.scale, pinchGestureRecognizer.scale);
            self.showImgView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeRedraw;

            self.editedImage=self.showImgView.image;
        }
        else if (pinchGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {


            if(view.frame.size.width <= self.cropFrame.size.width && view.frame.size.height <= self.cropFrame.size.height)
            {

                // Zoom out
                CGRect newFrame = self.showImgView.frame;

                UIImage *img=[self imageWithImage:self.originalImage scaledToSize:self.cropFrame.size];

                newFrame = [self handleScaleOverflow:CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height)];
                newFrame = [self handleBorderOverflow:CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height)];
                newFrame = [self handleScaleOverflow:newFrame];
                newFrame = [self handleBorderOverflow:newFrame];
                [UIView animateWithDuration:BOUNDCE_DURATION animations:^{
                    self.showImgView.frame = newFrame;
                    self.latestFrame = newFrame;
                    self.showImgView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
                    CGRect cropRect = AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(self.showImgView.image.size, self.showImgView.frame);

                    NSLog(@"frame %f %f ",cropRect.size.width,cropRect.size.height);
                }];
            }
            else

            {
                // Zoom In
                CGRect newFrame = self.showImgView.frame;
                newFrame = [self handleScaleOverflow:newFrame];
                newFrame = [self handleBorderOverflow:newFrame];
                [UIView animateWithDuration:BOUNDCE_DURATION animations:^{
                    self.showImgView.frame = newFrame;
                    self.latestFrame = newFrame;
                }];
            }

        }
    }
```