# How to import SKTUtils in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, swift, bridging

I'm trying to import [SKTUtils](https://github.com/raywenderlich/SKTUtils) - which is a set of swift files - into an Objective-C project. As far as I know it would be enough to do this way:

```
#import "ProjectName-Swift.h"
```

But the problem is that [SKTUtils](https://github.com/raywenderlich/SKTUtils) is not a project, but rather a directory with a set of swift classes. I tried to import the files this way:

```
#import "Vector3-Swift.h"
#import "CGFloat+Extensions-Swift.h"
.... etcetera ....
```

But without success. I've also set to yes the define modules option inside the project's build setting but still nothing to do.

Answer (score -1):

I have just tried to import SKTUtils in blank Objective-C Xcode project.

Looks like you are missing the following part of requirement for correct bridging:

> You need to import ProjectName-Swift.h. Note that it's the project name - the other answers make the mistake of using the class name.
>
> This single file is an autogenerated header that defines Objective-C interfaces for all Swift classes in your project **that are either annotated @objc or inherit from NSObject.**

taken from [How to import Swift code to Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24102880/598057).

For example in my test project my `Project-Swift.h` does contain imports of SKTUtils's extensions of SKAction because they are Objective-C-based classes of SpriteKit but some other stuff is not Objective-C friendly that's why you cannot access it because it is just not generated in `-Swift.h` file.

Another example is that I start seeing `SKTAudio` class in my Objective-C code if I make it a subclass of `NSObject`:

```
 @objc public class SKTAudio: NSObject {
```

Comment: But it's not a project, it's just a set of swift files.

Comment: In `#import "ProjectName-Swift.h"` `ProjectName` is your main project, it is not! the name of Swift project you want to import (SKTUtils in this case).

Comment: From what I see in SKTUtils, it is not written to play well with Objective-C. You can request support of it on their issue tracker or hack on its source yourself, though former is better of course.

Comment: SKTUtils is not a project. It's just a directory with some swift files inside it, that's what I meant.

Comment: I didn't get why my answer had got this -1. Please explain.