# importing swift file to obj-c

Tags: ios, socket.io, objective-c-swift-bridge

Okay, this one is too much for me. I'm trying to import manually file from socket-io which are written in swift, to my project who is fully written in obj-c.

I have read the doc from [Swift and obj-c](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-ID138), but that's not really helpful at all. And from [socket-io](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift), same thing. All it says is to download the github project, import the "source" folder to my obj-c project, and then follow the instruction from Apple doc which to my opinion are definitively not clear at all.

My question is: what is the concept of swift module? Because I definitively didn't found what conceptually is a module, and how to build it from a folder of swift file, even if I think it is a collection of swift class, but with Apple, I'm not even sure of this.

my project is structured like this:

```
.
+-- projectName
+-- Source
|   +-- SockectFile_0.swift
|   +-- SockectFile_1.swift
|   +-- SockectFile_2.swift
|   +-- SockectFile_3.swift

+-- ViewController
|   +-- viewController_0.h
|   +-- viewController_0.m
```

Then how to import the whole "Source" folder with all this files inside to my viewController_0.m ? I don't have even any idea how to compile it as a module. Or if it is the right way to do it. Like I said, I'm in a confused state right now.

Thanks for the answers in advance.

**Note**
After further research, I have give it up. What I did is compile the entire swift project alone and import it as framework. But of course, it is too much for Xcode to handle the framework as a fat binary. Sorry if I look gross, but I don't understand why Xcode is a sooooooooooo bad IDE tool. For info, it took me approximatively 1 minute to import socketIO in my python project where it took me 3 hours with Xcode with the source code, and I just dodged the problem because what I did is the binary solution (Xcode is even not good at making a simple fat binary by itself. Where it took 3 lines of script to implement). I really hate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102104/how-to-import-swift-code-to-objective-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Making Swift Module

You have to follow these steps
Goto Build Setting > Search =  Defines Module to **YES** then > Search product module name and give name for your Module there
[image]

Then

[image]

Your Can use your Module Like `@import MQTTKit;`

[image]