# How to create Onboarding through SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm creating an app that will have an onboarding page, like in the application of [Telegram](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HNS5Lo9ZIcQ).

How can I create such a page without cocoaPods? I came to the conclusion that it is possible to implement through a **SpriteKit** view in a view controller with animation image.

I'm having a problem with the connection between the Sprite Kit view and the view controller. How can I correctly add a Sprite Kit scene to a view controller?

I write on the application in **Objective C**.
Thanks for any suggestions! This my first app and I'm very excited to hear your suggestions.

[image]

Comment: Take a look to this interesting project https://github.com/jhurt/GBPageControl  , i think it can help you.

Comment: @Alessandro Ornano Yes, thank you, but in the realization of this example, Swift and I need to implementation on ObjC. Is there such about ObjC ?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102104/how-to-import-swift-code-to-objective-c

Comment: @Alessandro Ornano Can I add the GBPageControl framework to ObjC proj ? or this framework only on Swift ?

Comment: GBPageControl is not a framework, is a simple library. You can import a Swift library in your ObjC project follow the link I've writed in the last comment.

Comment: @Alessandro Ornano Thank you, but I have to find an implementation entirely on objC.

Comment: If you know Swift, instead of finding it or waiting for it, try to translate it. It's simple, few lines, it could be doing in half hour.