# Using Swift file in Objective C Test Cases

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, unit-testing

I am trying to use an `Swift` file in `Objective C` unit tests. I am unable to import my Swift file in to objective c unit test. When i try to do `#import "ProjectName-Swift.h"`. it gives me the `'ProjectName-Swift.h' file not found` error.

Any idea how i can use my swift file in Objective C Unit tests.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102104/how-to-import-swift-code-to-objective-c

Comment: Thats not woking for me. As i told you i already tried this