# iOS - Implementing UI on Objective-c and Swift together

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

A legacy project was done on Objective-c, where there is a tab view. A full new feature is required with a new tab which I want to implement on Swift. Right now there is no time to convert full project into Swift but the new feature is to be implemented on Swift. Can anyone guide me how can I implement the new feature in Swift just adding a new Tab on Objective-c UI.

Comment: This can achieved by using a bridge header class. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102104/how-to-import-swift-code-to-objective-c, refer this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can confidently start using `Swift` files in your `Objective-C` project. There is no need to convert full project into `Swift`

You can follow below steps to use `Swift` class in your project:

- Create new Controller Class in `Swift`.
- It will pop up for `Bridge-Header` file, create it.
- If you want to use any `Objective-C` class into your `Swift` file just import that `Objective-C` file into your `Bridge-Header`.
- If you want to use `Swift` class file into your `Objective-C` controller so import "ProjectName-Swift.h" into your `Objective-C` controller class.

**important :** `"ProjectName-Swift.h"` would be Module name. If you have multiple targets in your project the use `"TargetName-Swift.h"`

Please follow below links:
[https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift)

[How to call Objective-C code from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift)

[How to import Swift code to Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102104/how-to-import-swift-code-to-objective-c)