# how to use objective c view controller in swift3 project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am trying to add objective c view controller in the swift project.so some help me out solve this.

```
    let objCObject = SampleClass()   //   objectiv C object Class
    objCObject.run

    let objCObject1 = SampleViewController() // objective C viewcontroller
    objCObject1.run
```

Thanks for quick response.

Comment: Use Bridge for this

Comment: use objective-C Bridging header for it

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift

Comment: Refere my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41156897/ios-implementing-ui-on-objective-c-and-swift-together/41156983#41156983

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Bridging Header`. Here are the steps to do that.

Click on your project target, Go to `Build Settings` tab, search for `Bridging Header`. You can see the `Xcode` generated path entry.

Select it and click on delete button.

Also, make sure to delete the Xcode auto generated `Bridging Header` file `ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h` from your `Xcode` project directory.

Now, try to import the `Objective-C` file once again. You can see the prompt to create a `Bridging Header` file as expected.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make one `.h` file and `import` all objective c files like `Myfile.h` into that Header file just you make.

Now into build settings, Find `Objective-C Bridging Header` and give path of this file

Now you can use any `Objective-C` file into `Swift`

Hope this will helps