# Objective c and Swift using in Framework in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, frameworks

I've my own old framework which is only compatible in objective c, but Now I open in new xcode and added few swift classes (Xcode not gave me option to create bridging as this do in normal App when you add swift class in objective c project), Also Xcode gave me suggestion to update build setting and I updated those and currently I'm on **Xcode 8.2.1**. Now I try to build but I am getting few error as you can see in picture . I googled and found solution to delete derive data and quite xcode and open and clean. I done Everything but didn't workout.

- Is bridging can be possible in framwork.
- If not possible then how can I achieve.

Need help and suggestion.
[image]

Comment: "open in new xcode and added few swift classes" Within framework?

Comment: Is there a swift header file? Refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/24102880/742298

Comment: @Dili I am created my own framework, and before it was only in objective c now I added few swift files

Comment: @AshutoshDave No I don't have any swift file "ProjectName-Swift.h", I think this create because of bridging suggestion which I didn't get while adding new swift file

Answer (score 2):

When you are mixing Swift/Objc inside a framework, you can import Swift code for Objective-C use and import Objective-C from Swift.

First, ensure that `Define Settings` is set for the current framework target.

**To import Swift into Objective-C:**
In each Objective-C file that requires the Swift code, import the generated Swift header **with the complete current Framework Path** : `#import <Framework/Framework-Swift.h>`

**To import Objective-C into Swift:**

Ensure you have an umbrella header. The path can be found inside the `Build Settings` of the target. In this header, import all the needed Objective-C headers like normally in Objective-C: `#import "Header"`

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-ID122

Comment: Awesome. Critical point here was that `"Framework-Swift.h"` did not work, it has to be imported using `<Framework/Framework-Swift.h>`.