# How I can get reference of Swift AppDelegate from objective c code

Tags: objective-c, swift

My Project is in Swift 3.0 and I am using xCode8.2. I need to import objective C code in my swift project.  objective C  required app delegate reference. How can I get swift appdelegate reference from my objective C code?

In my objective C file  #import "AppDelegate.h" is giving not found error as it is swift AppDelegate

Comment: Are you using the objective c code form your swift code? Is it initalized in swift with an app delegate?

Comment: MY project is in Swift , I have a module which is build in Objective C. in that objective c module it require appdelegate reference.

Comment: I need it in reverse. From Objective c code I need a reference of swift appdelegate. #import "AppDelegate.h" is giving not found error as it is swift AppDelegate

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Kie already said, you need to `#import "<ProductModuleName>-Swift.h"` in your Obj-C `.m` file to get all Swift classes. Here a sample project with what you need https://github.com/aminbenarieb/Researches/tree/master/Swift/Swift_ObjC.

**Update**:
If your can't see Swift files in Objective-C files, make sure you have the `Objective-C bridging header`, as follows in [Apple Documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)

> Importing Objective-C into Swift
>
> To import a set of Objective-C files in the same app target as your
>   Swift code, you rely on an Objective-C bridging header to expose those
>   files to Swift. Xcode offers to create this header file when you add a
>   Swift file to an existing Objective-C app, or an Objective-C file to
>   an existing Swift app.

Comment: I did the similar this like your Foo.m , I added #import "MyProjectName-Swift.h in the ObjC.m file . But It says not able to find MyProjectName-Swift.h file.

Comment: @AvijitDas,
1. To download the code make sure that `git` installed on you machine and - run in terminal:
`git clone https://github.com/aminbenarieb/Researches.git Researches
cd Researches
git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter Swift/Swift_ObjC HEAD 
`
- otherwise you manually [download project](https://github.com/aminbenarieb/Researches/archive/master.zip) and find SwiftObjC project folder.

Have you added the `Objective-C bridging header `?

Answer (score 8):

I am not sure if this answers your question.

**Getting AppDelegate in Swift**

You can call objective-c code from Swift and if your Objective-C code needs an AppDelegate for it to work in some calls you can gat this by calling `UIApplication.shared.delegate` in Swift.

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

**Getting AppDelegate in Objective-C**

If you need the AppDelegate in your Objective-C code thats the way:

```
#import "<ProductModuleName>-Swift.h" // You have to replace with your swift module name
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Comment: I need it in reverse. From Objective c code I need a reference of swift appdelegate. #import "AppDelegate.h" is giving not found error as it is swift AppDelegate

Comment: I edited my answer. To really help you, it'll help if you could post some of your code next time. Thank you.

Comment: I guess it is because you didn't figure out how to import your swift header. I added a line, but this will only work if your Objective-C code is compiled in the same target. More information on that here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html
Btw: I don't think that's a nice down-vote since I am making an effort to help you, despite that the information you are giving is lacking.

Comment: Sorry for the down vote as I thought you are not getting my question and you are answering in reverses way. I just saw your comment and undo it. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html This link I saw.  I gave "#import "MyProjectBundleName-Swift.h"  in the objective C class. But when I am trying to compile its not finding the header file.

Comment: What is your Bundle name?

Comment: Additionally is to add that if you are trying to use a framework you have to do additionally steps. Let me know if that is the case.

Comment: Hi , It Worked , Thanks. I need to make few settings in my Build settings from the instruction in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102104/how-to-import-swift-code-to-objective-c?rq=1

Comment: Should I need to add `#import "AppDelegate.swift"` file in `ProjectName-Swift.h` file ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding some color to the answers from Kie and Amin: I was struggling with how to adapt `#import "<ProductModuleName>-Swift.h"` into something that made sense for my project. I was getting header file not found compile-time error, and it turned out that non-alphanumeric characters in `ProductModuleName` are replaced with underscores when the bridge header is created. In my case I had a space in the product name; once I replaced the space with an underscore the compile-time error was resolved. Seems trivial now, but I'm just starting out.

Here's the reference to Apple's documentation and relevant snippet:

> The header's name is generated from your product module name, followed by "-Swift.h". By default, this name is the same as your product name, with any non-alphanumeric characters replaced with an underscore (_). If the name begins with a number, the first digit is replaced with an underscore.

[Importing Swift into Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_swift_into_objective-c)