# Access IOs library and export mp3 file using swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I would like to access IOS music library with swift 3.0 and xcode 8.2.1 and export this mp3 file to whatsapp or any other messaging app.
I have searched about this topic but none of the codes I found here work with this xcode version..

can you help me?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library to export the iOS music content to your project document.

https://github.com/tapsquare/TSLibraryImport

Note: This is Objective-C library for managing this library. You need to create Bridging Header file to and #import "TSLibraryImport.h" file.

For adding Objective C inside Swift project check below link:

1. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html
2. [How to import Swift code to Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102104/how-to-import-swift-code-to-objective-c)