# Cannot assign protocol-conforming Objective-C class to a property with Swift Protocol

Tags: objective-c, swift, protocols, bridging-header, objc-bridging-header

I'm trying to have an Objective-C class adopt a protocol written in a Swift file. I've got Swift an Objective-C inter-operating to some extent.  (I can construct my Objective-C class from Swift).

I have:

```
@objc public protocol FooProtocol {
    func foobar()
}
```

Then, my Objective-C file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SwiftObjcProtocolTest-Bridging-Header.h"

@protocol FooProtocol
@end

@interface ObjClass1 : NSObject <FooProtocol>

-(void)foobar;

@end
```

and impl:

```
#import "ObjClass1.h"

@implementation ObjClass1

- (void)foobar {
    NSLog(@"foobar protocol function called");
}

@end
```

But when I give Swift (doing this mostly in app delegate) a delegate property and try to assign the Objective-C object to it:

```
var delegate: FooProtocol?
....
delegate = objcInstance
delegate?.foobar()
```

it fails with:

> cannot assign value of type 'ObjClass1' to  type 'FooProtocol?'.

I've tried coercing it with `as! FooProtocol` but this results in a SIGABRT.

What is the issue here?

Comment: What, if you completely delete the protocol definition in the header file?

Answer (score 0):

To get this working I found that:

1. Make sure to import your Swift code into Objective-C ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26873548/1305067)). Import it into `ObjClass1.m`.
2. Your forward declaration of the protocol `FooProtocol` should look like this:

   ```
   @protocol FooProtocol;
   ```

instead of:

```
    @protocol FooProtocol
    @end
```

**Note:** Although this worked for me, there is probably a better solution out there as I get a warning in `ObjClass1.h` saying `Cannot find protocol definition for 'FooProtocol'`.

Comment: i get the warning you mentioned twice ( the warning is repeated indicated to me Xcode isn't doing too fell with my setup).  Also. i'm getting `I_OBJC_PROTOCOL_$_FooProtocol, referenced from:` and than nothing. and `linker command failed with exit code (-v for more..)`.  and whats odd is clicking these errors doesn't even take me to more information further indicating something is buggy or not setup right here.