# I want to implement following drop down feature in my iOS Application. How Can do it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, drop-down-menu

This is screen shot, in the last drop down menu is there, I clicked it and it's showing some menus that one

[image]

but instead of that, here I want to add sorting menus like,

```
1. sort by date
2. sort by name
3. sort by ...etc
```

Comment: and also, Anybody tell me , how can Implement sorting technique..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For short array by a key.. Like Name....Put the key on which you want to short your array

This will Short your array Ascending

```
 NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Your Key"  ascending:YES  selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
 NSArray *shortedArray=[Your array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];
```

This will Short your array Decending

```
 NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Your Key"  ascending:NO  selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
 NSArray *shortedArray=[Your array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];
```

Comment: Yea, right one..!

Answer (score 1):

i used [DropDown](https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown) for my project, we can easily customize these DropDownCell(customCell) & Appearance too.

You can able to integrate with your project through PODS

> pod 'DropDown'

Comment: Thanks for this help, but my project is in Objective c...! Any other solution ?

Comment: You can integrate swift into Obj-c.check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102104/how-to-import-swift-code-to-objective-c