# Generate property of NSObject Class in swift to objective C

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am using a **NSObject** class in **Swift**, I want to access the property of that class in **Objective-C**

Below is the class of Swift

```
class JobCategoryNew:NSObject {

var category_data:String = ""
var category_data_all: [CategoryData] = [CategoryData]()    
}
```

How can I import JobCategoryNew in my **Objective-C** file and how to create the object?

Comment: is that you create swift header file like "ProjectName-Swift.h"?

Comment: yes, i create it

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/31242085/6028575

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102104/how-to-import-swift-code-to-objective-c > This can be helpful too.

Comment: also you have to make class public like @objc public class JobCategoryNew: NSObject

Comment: getting file not found error using #Import "YourProjectName-swift.h"

Comment: have you replace projectName

Comment: yes, but not working for me :(

Answer (score 1):

First follow all the steps given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/41068740/6028575 
and
finally your swift class should like be

```
import Foundation

@objc
class JobCategoryNew:NSObject {

   var category_data:String = ""
var category_data_all: [CategoryData] = [CategoryData]() 
}
```

**Usage**

```
JobCategoryNew *obj = [[JobCategoryNew alloc] init];
obj.category_data = @"Testing!!!";
```