# 'PusherSwift/PusherSwift-Swift.h' file not found in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, apple-push-notifications, pusherswift

I am trying to implement PusherSwift in Objective-C.

I got pusher sample code from https://github.com/pusher/pusher-websocket-swift/releases

When I am running the code, I found an error "'PusherSwift/PusherSwift-Swift.h' file not found".

Then I search about it, But I can't found the solution.

I code already have the things mentioned in the steps followed by the link https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/1470256/A-step-by-step-guide-to-installing-Pushe.

Is it need to implement the bridging concept for this scenario?

Is there anyone implemented pusherSwift in objective-c?

If yes Please help me.

Comment: try  #import "PusherSwift-Swift.h" in your objective c file.

Comment: Yes you need to Create BridgeHeader when you use Swift code in objective c or vice versa. so create bridge header file and then import your swift file on that bridge and then use it. this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102104/how-to-import-swift-code-to-objective-c

Comment: Error is gone when I re-import the framework.

Comment: But I found another run time error                                              dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/PusherSwift.framework/PusherSwift
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/1287E86C-B618-4D3D-A62B-08C665DD435B/LycaVideo.app/LycaVideo
  Reason: image not found