# iOS - Generated IPA sized grow a lot after create new target

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Before create a target the IPA size was 6MB after add a new target the new size is 90MB.
It's insane, what's going on?

I had to make several changes in order to run objective-c and swift

Instructions from the Apple website:

> To import Swift code into Objective-C from the same framework
>
> Under **Build Settings**, in **Packaging**, make sure the **Defines Module**
>   setting for that framework target is set to **Yes**. Import the Swift code
>   from that framework target into any Objective-C .m file within that
>   framework target using this syntax and substituting the appropriate
>   names:
>
> **#import "ProductName-Swift.h"**

And this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44904162/2139691

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply creating a target cannot change the IPA size because an IPA is the result of compiling and archiving 1 target.
It is what you embed in this target and its configuration that will have an impact on the size of the IPA, for instance:

- Resources (images, videos)
- Linked libraries and frameworks
- Use of Swift as the Swift libraries will be embedded in the IPA
- ARM Architectures in the build settings

You can rename your `MyApp.ipa` into `MyApp.zip` and unzip it to browse the content of your application and detect what is taking so much space.

You can also have a look at the *Build Phases* tab of your target in Xcode to see what is embedded in the IPA during the build.