# Add Multiple Target Header in IOS Objective-C code

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am working on a project written in Objective-C. Current app has three target based on environment(Dev, Prelive and Live).

Now I have to add new functionality which must be written in Swift language. I follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102104/how-to-import-swift-code-to-objective-c)  and app complied successfully in Dev target (i.e. Environment) .

In objective-C files I have added header as below

*#import "Dev-Swift.h"*

and I have imported above 'Dev-Swift.h' in multiple files.

Now issue is that I have three target and suppose If I have to run on any other target(Say Prelive) then I have to made changes with header again in multiple files & it will be

*import "Prelive-Swift.h"*

which will be again a tough task & may leads error while changing target.

Can any one suggest how to tackle this issue. I do not want change header every time when I change target.

Let me know if I have clarify question more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try to put the same name for the three environment.
in this case you don't need to change the file name each time 
like this : 
[image]