# Swift Transfer -> Array to ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have problem and i cannot fix it by using google.
I have string array (written in swift). But i have objectiveC files with chart functions.

I need transfer whole swift array into objectiveC file.

Example of array:

```
for i in 0...11 { 
    mainSelectionMonthArrayValues.append(
        String(WatchlistViewController().fetchDataMonth(
            type:1, month: i+1, year: 2017)
        )
    ) 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "transfer whole swift array to objective C file"? Please explain

Comment: Are you basically asking how to call the objective-c methods from your swift code?

Comment: i have array in swift and wanna call it in objective C

Comment: How are you exposing it, where is it stored? Have you imported your Swift header into your Objective-C file as mentioned here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102104/how-to-import-swift-code-to-objective-c

We might need to see more code before we can fully understand what the issue is.

Comment: I try it again with importing header file into swift. Thanks for answers!

Comment: How is `mainSelectionMonthArrayValues` declared?  You probably need to declare it as (or bridge it to) `NSArray`.

Comment: Yes. Declaration is: var mainSelectionMonthArrayValues = [String]() ... But transfering into NSArray dont works for me :/

Answer (score -1):

Given you are not very specific about the code that "does not work" or the specific error you get it is hard to answer anything precisely. But given what Google finds in books for "cocoa pass swift string array  to objective-c" you will have

> To call an `NSArray` function on a Swift array you may have to cast to `NSArray`

so it is a pretty safe bet you will have to do this too if you want to pass `mainSelectionMonthArrayValues` to an Objective-C method (with an appropriate interface). Casting to an Objective-C class will not be free in most cases, but it is likely to be a constant time operation. Note however, that you will have to coerce if your object needs to be mutable on the Objective-C end. So try passing your array using something like

```
objCRef.callObjCMethod(mainSelectionMonthArrayValues as NSArray)
```

If this again "does not work" then you should provide us with more info on the kind of error you experience.