# Bridge Objective-C to Swift for accessing other CocoaPods

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I'm using Objective-C and I need to implement some third party tools using CocoaPods, but it is available in Swift, so I need to bridge. How can I bridge Objective-C to Swift?

Comment: Check this :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102104/how-to-import-swift-code-to-objective-c

Comment: The library you want to use is in Swift, or in ObjC?

Comment: Add the @objc keyword before the swift class name which you want to access in objective-c files.