# Fade in fade out animation when we joined two videos

Tags: ios, objective-c, video

I am working on concatenating videos. I have code which is giving successful concatenation results, but not showing fadeIn fadeOut transition when next video started. So, please guide me how I can do it. I want result like given following video url link. Please help me, I have been stuck on this for many days. [video url link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sr5T0.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the code that you are using to modify these videos.

Comment: @fin444 thanks for response. I am using following code https://github.com/mkoehnke/MKOVideoMerge

Comment: What "following code"?

Comment: I used github class which is in this link https://github.com/mkoehnke/MKOVideoMerge

Comment: See [KVVideoManager](https://github.com/khoavd-dev/MergeVideos) to joint two videos with animation.

Comment: I downloaded this project and run. It is giving desire result. Thanks @BhavinRamani

Comment: Welcome @vikranttanwar glad to hear that it helps you.

Comment: @BhavinRamani I am using Objective C so how I can use this lib in Objective C

Comment: @vikranttanwar You have to use `Bridging-Header`. For reference see this docs: [Swift and Objective-C in the Same Project](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102104/how-to-import-swift-code-to-objective-c

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164225/discussion-between-bhavin-ramani-and-vikrant-tanwar).