# Is bridging header file automatically generated while adding a Swift file to an objective-C project?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, bridging-header, objc-bridging-header

I added a swift class in my existing Objective-C project and was trying to import bridging header file of the form `#import <ProductName/ProductModuleName-Swift.h>` in some existing obj-c classes. But I got error that the header file is not found. I have put the correct Product name and Product Module Name but still I have no clue what exactly I am doing wrong. Also, I got this error: Umbrella header 'ProductName-umbrella.h' not found.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102104/how-to-import-swift-code-to-objective-c

Comment: Change Defines Module in build settings to yes.