# How to use Swift classes in Objective-C files in framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I build framework, which has both Obj-C and Swift file. I need to import Swift file into Obj-C file using:

```
#import "ProjectName-Swift.h"
```

All Build settings are default, despite Defines module set to YES, Obj-C Generated Interface Header Name to $(PROJECT_NAME)-Swift.h and Always embed Swift Standard Libraries to YES (for both project and target).

Unfortunately I have error:

```
'ProjectName-Swift.h' file not found
```

when I build the project. How should I cope with importing Swift file into Obj-C?

I need to import Swift to Obj-C, not the other way.

Comment: I need to import Swift to Obj-C, not the other way. @SPatel

Comment: Create swift file (File -> New -> Swift), xcode should create bridging header. Then try rebuild.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102104/how-can-i-import-swift-code-to-objective-c

Comment: Bridging header is not supported by frameworks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI the solution to this issue is just changing

```
#import "ProjectName-Swift.h"
```

into

```
#import "ProjectName/ProjectName-Swift.h"
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to the given answers.

Make sure your swift class is like this..

```
@objcMembers class SomeClass: NSObject {
  //Whatever you wish
}
```

This @objcMembers does the magic.

This is important since your objects need to be compiled into objc objects.