# Calling to a variable of swift view controller file in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a project that is a cross of Swift and Objective-C using a bridging-header.

In my main ViewController.swift file, outside of the class declaration, I have this code:

```
var mainView = ViewController()
```

In other views that I segue to, I can use this to call a function to run back on the main ViewController by using `mainView.runFunction()`

How can I call this function in an Objective-C .m implementation file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all for using swift in objective-c you need to import `TargetName-Swift.h`. Note that it's the target name.

For more information look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24102880/7629882).

You can achieve what you want in this way:

```
ViewController *mainView = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[mainView runFunction];
```

Also you should declare your `runFunction` with `@objc` to use it in objective-c like below:

```
@objc func runFunction {
    // what you want to do ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Even though I have a ViewController.swift file and added `@objc` to its class definition, your code pops up the error "Unknown receiver ViewController" - if I add the `#import "project-Swift.h"` then the view controller is recognized in the first line of your code, but the second line shows error `"No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector 'runFunction'"`

Comment: @RanLearns answer updated. that was a slip of the tongue!

Answer (score 0):

Follow this apple article and done : [Load Swift in Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_swift_into_objective-c).
Or I already did is a "trick" using "@objc" key, look at this little explanation: [What is @objc attribute](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-is-the-objc-attribute), one easy way is just create a helper function that will be visible to your Objective-c class and done like:

```
@objc func retrieveMainView() -> UIViewController { return MyViewController() }
```

And you call this from your objective-c class, maybe you need to anotate your swift class with @objc, look at this two reference and you will get the idea and figure out for sure .

Answer (score 0):

In your Objective file i.e. .m file add below import statement:

```
import "<ProjectName>-Swift.h"
```

For example your project name is MyProject, so import statement would look like:

```
import "MyProject-Swift.h"
```

And call your function like: `[mainView runFunction];`

I hope this will help. You can also refer one of my answer:
[How can I import Swift code to Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102104/how-can-i-import-swift-code-to-objective-c/41010872#41010872)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I believe my import statement is correct (no errors upon running) but the [mainView runFunction]; is erroring as `Use of undeclared identifier 'mainView'`

Comment: Yes, thank you. I marked another answer as correct. I had to instantiate a ViewController before I could call a function on it.