# Unable to import Swift code to Objective-C project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I am trying to import a swift class to my objective-c project but I get "Use of undeclared identifier" error inside my .m file when I try to use the swift class.

Inside my swift class there is an "@objc" marker. When I created the swift class I added the bridge file. I also checked those values:

> Defines Module : YES
>
> Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries : YES
>
> Install Objective-C Compatibility Header : YES

Also in Target/Build Settings/Objective-c Bridging Header I checked that the path to the bridging file is correct.

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to write something inside the bridging file?

Comment: How did you import your swift file to objective c? Add some relevant code, related to that bridging file and import statement

Comment: I created a new .swift file and copy paste the code. The bridging file created autonomously by Xcode.

Comment: So you imported that "modulename-Swift.h" in your objective c file ?

Comment: Please refer this ~> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102104/how-can-i-import-swift-code-to-objective-c

Comment: @MidhunMP yes I did, but when I try to use the swift class I get this error

Comment: @MidhunMP Actually the name of the file is "myapp-Bridging-Header.h"

Comment: Recheck all your points by refering this https://medium.com/@nimjea/swift-objective-c-mixed-languages-app-16b6c9c3e9b0

Comment: @Student No, you are using the wrong bridging header

Comment: @MidhunMP which one is the correct then?This file was generated from xcode.

Comment: @Student This bridging header is to expose ObjC classes to Swift, you need to use the bridging header which is generated automatically when you build the project. Which is not added to project

Comment: Usually the bridging header name will be, your targetname-Swift.h. Check the links attached by @dahiya_boy

Comment: @MidhunMP but when I try to build the project it fails.

Comment: @MidhunMP I checked the link, but I can't figure it out. How to create this myapp-Swfit.h? Manually? I actually did and linked it to the Objective-C Bridging Header but the problem remains.

Comment: @Student: You don't need to create that file manually, it will be generated automatically. It's not replace `myapp` with your target/app name.