# How to access Swift class from Objective-C class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I want to access swift class(variables and methods) in my objC class.

I have created a **YourProjectName-Swift.h** file.

1. set "**Defines Module**" to YES in build setting
2. check **Product Module Name** the same with my swift file name.
3. set **Install Objective-C Compatibility Header** to YES
4. set **Objective-C Generated Interface Header** : YourProjectName-Swift.h
5. then Import Swift interface header in *.m file.

```
#import "YourProjectName-Swift.h"
```

My swift class is:

```
@objc public class MySwiftClass: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addBehavior()
    }

    
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        addBehavior()
    }

    func addBehavior() {
        print("Add all the behavior here")
    }
}
```

How can I access this class from an Objective-C file?

I tried to initiate my swift class object with the below, but it's not working.

```
MySwiftClass *swift = [[MySwiftClass alloc] init];
```

Comment: did you build (cmd+b) first before calling it in obj-c?

Comment: yes, i did this

Comment: did autocomplete not work? because in the MySwiftClass you need frame param for init, but you called init without any param

Comment: xcode not giving any suggestion in init this class

Comment: Please check this URL :- https://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-use-swift-classes-in-objective-c/

Comment: i tested with new project, its working fine. but its taking some time to show swift class in objective c class. when i run the build and after i tried, suggestion are showing,
please check this URL :- https://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-use-swift-classes-in-objective-c/

Comment: Check Screenshot :- https://prnt.sc/tdxvi9

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I import Swift code to Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102104/how-can-i-import-swift-code-to-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

You **shouldn't** create YourProjectName-Swift.h file. It will be generated **automatically** for you!

Just import YourProjectName-Swift.h in **your ObjC class** where you want to access swift class, and use it.

Considerations:

> If your target name contains spaces, replace them with underscores
> (e.g. **Your Project Name** becomes Your_Project_Name-Swift.h)
>
> If your target is a framework, you need to import
> <YourProjectName/YourProjectName-Swift.h>

Answer (score 0):

Add
'@class MySwiftClass' in '.h' file of objective C