# Importing Swift Class into Obj-C in React Native module

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, react-native

I am developing a new feature for a react native module (https://github.com/blackuy/react-native-twilio-video-webrtc) the thing is it is developed in Objective-C and I need to import a new Swift class.

What I've done so far:

1. Importing it with the name of the package, in this case `#import <RNTwilioVideoWebRTC/RNTwilioVideoWebRTC-Swift.h>`
2. Ensuring that Precompile Bridging Header is set to Yes
3. Setting `Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name` as RNTwilioVideoWebRTC-Swift.h

The problem is then i try to run the example app inside the module, it prompts an error `RNTwilioVideoWebRTC/RNTwilioVideoWebRTC-Swift.h file not found`

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Is the class and its functions annotated with `@objc`?

Comment: Yes, I've already tried with `@objc` and `@objcMember`

Comment: @EduardoPalacio Currently, dealing with the same thing, I tried everything I was able to find, but with no luck. Have you ever found an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Archiving will be successful already tested**

***How to call a swift function (that could be in a swift framework also) in objective c project or react native project***

*it will work for react-native also*
follow these steps :

> Open Build Settings and check these parameters:
> **Defines Module : YES**

> in AppDelegate.h

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class KB;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, RCTBridgeDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) KB *appkb;

@end
```

> in AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ProductModuleName-Swift.h"
@implementation AppDelegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [self.appkb methodReceiveSwiftClass];
  [self.appkb methodEvents:event prop:properties];
}

@end
```

> KB.swift

```
import Foundation
// import framework if using a swift framework in objective c or react native native modules.
@objc public class KB:NSObject{
  
  @objc public func methodReceiveSwiftClass(){
    //write anything here....
  }

  @objc public func methodEvents(_ event: String, prop: String){
    //write anything here
     //func with params
  }

}
```

> ProjectModuleName-Bridging-Header.h

```
#import "React/RCTBridgeModule.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

Answer (score 1):

I've added the Resolve & Reject approach. It is very simple and easy to share the data/calling function in React native with iOS Native.

**Create a new swift file with the same name as ObjC -**

//Example.swift

```
import Foundation

@objc(Example)
class Example: NSObject {

 @objc static func requiresMainQueueSetup() -> Bool { return true }

  @objc func testing(_ data: String, key: String, _ resolve: RCTPromiseResolveBlock, rejecter reject: RCTPromiseRejectBlock) -> Void {
    
//do your logics here, just update your "value" in the condition

    if(value != nil) {
      resolve(value)
    } else {
      let error = NSError(domain: "", code: 200, userInfo: nil)
      reject("E_COUNT", "count cannot be negative", error)
    }
  }
}
```

**Create bridging Header ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h and add below code**

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
```

**Add new Objective C .m file**

//Example.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(Example, NSObject)

/* Bridging Delegates */

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(testing:(NSString *)name key:(NSString *)key: (RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
  rejecter: (RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)

@end
```

**React Native js class:**

```
import { NativeModules, Platform } from 'react-native';

//Call your native swift function from here.

NativeModules.Example.testing(
      paramOne, paramTwo).then((response) => {
        return ({
          response
        })
      }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e.message, e.code)
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to make sure that:

1. Check whether the bridging file is available in your project or not. If available, make sure that you have imported `YourProductName-Swift.h` in your bridge file. And if not, please create a bridge file.
2. Mark the class & methods with `@objc` to make them accessible in your `Objective C` code.

You can follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24102880/7210270) for reference.