# Xcode 6 GM - Build error when copying generated "MyAppName-Swift" header file?

Tags: xcode, xcode6, xcode6gm

Below is the error I'm getting when building my application. Does anyone have experience with this error?

> ditto: can't get real path for source '/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAppName-fwxrneawhopjkqcpeoykduytrgwv/Build/Intermediates/MyAppName.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyAppName.build/Objects-normal/arm64/MyAppName-Swift.h'
>
> Command /usr/bin/ditto failed with exit code 1

Any help would be great!

If more info is needed, please ask. :)

Comment: [Here's a thread](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/245001) I made on Apple's developer forums about my problem.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062618/swift-to-objective-c-header-not-created-in-xcode-6

Answer (score 11):

Crazy right? Did the super clean, Command - Option - Shift. Cleared it up. Was stunned that it worked.

Comment: Did for me too. I also had an error stating: "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed". Both disappeared. This all happened to me when upgrading to Xcode 7.2.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too. I realized that by commenting out most of my swift code it would build properly. Gradually, line by line, I uncommented code until I found an error in my swift code that was masked by this error. Now the app builds just fine.

Comment: I only had this problem with my Swift framework. Once I decided to just add the framework's source code to my project directly (rather than building it as a a framework) did it work properly. Quite strange.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, when I accidentally removed some swift file from disk.

Answer (score 0):

Just Clean and build the code, it will work fine.
clean -> shift + command + K.

Answer (score 0):

#### Do a "Super Clean"

1. Clear derived data folder *Xcode, Preferences, Locations, Click First Arrow*
2. Clean build folder <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>
3. Clean Project <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>

Restart Xcode for good measure. *MAGIC*