# "XXX-Swift.h" file not found in test project

Tags: ios, swift, import, header-files, xctest

I'm trying to call a method of a `NSObject` subclass I have in the let's say "main" project within a method of a `XCTestCase` subclass in the test project. The `NSObject` subclass of the main project imports the "XXX-Swift.h" header file (I'm mixing `Swift` and `Objective-C` code). All works fine when I run the main project, but when I run the tests calling an object of that subclass, I get an error saying that the `Swift` header file in the import is not found.

I guess I'm missing some settings in the test target, but I don`t find which... what should I check? Or what should I do to solve this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Go to Xcode Project > Build Settings and type "header name", you will get the below option:

[image]

Make sure that there must exist a file with a name: `$(SWIFT_MODULE_NAME)-Swift.h`

Then type, "bridging header" under Build Settings and make sure that the path of "bridging-header.h" file exist correctly.

[image]

Edited:

1) Make sure that your "Project Name" doesn't contains spaces
2) Well "XXX-Swift.h" file is generated at the following path, so you need to add that path to unit test - Go to build settings, type "Header Search Paths" and add the following line

```
"$(TARGET_TEMP_DIR)/../$(PROJECT_NAME).build/DerivedSources"
```

For more, you can refer this link : [iOS - 'MyProject-Swift.h' file not found when running Unit Tests for Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26473058/ios-myproject-swift-h-file-not-found-when-running-unit-tests-for-swift)

Comment: I already have those settings in the app target, and I've set `Embedded Content Contains Swift Code` to YES in the test target, but it is still working when I run the app, but gettings the error when running the tests...

Comment: I still get the error... how could I see the value of $(TARGET_TEMP_DIR)?

Comment: @AppsDev You can know it from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233581/xcode-4-build-output-directory

Comment: After doing this my test target can see XXXTests-Swift.h however the file contains a line to @import XXX; which it cannot resolve

Comment: Remember to do the import of 'MyProject-Swift.h' in the .m file AND ALSO VERY IMPORTANT IN MY CASE in a place not limited by #ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED or #if DEBUG!