# Swift header stop compiled

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have very strange error.

I  am using a Swift class in Objective-c.  I have `Bridging-Header.h` created, import `MyProject-Swift.h` in my file, and all WORKS perfectly!

So, now i meet a very strange error. I made no changes in projects settings, no change in swift files or something else. When i build now the project, i receive this error `MyProject-Swift.h file not found`  suddenly.

I checked all Settings in Project:

Defines Modules is set to `YES`

Objective-c generated interface header is set to `MyProject-Swift.h`

MyProject name is not contains space!

And isn't work for any file: .h or .m

EDIT:

Is weird because i can se swift class in my objective-c file, and i can use it, but i take always the only error: `MyProject-Swift.h file not found`

Comment: Please check in your build phases  - > compile sources ..that "MyProject-Swift.h" file is there or not . if missing then add .

Comment: I don't have it there any file "MyPoject-Swift.h" and i can't add it

Comment: I have Swift class there

Comment: I find no file called MyProject-Swift.h in my project to add it

Comment: see this link may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31557345/xxx-swift-h-file-not-found-in-test-project