# Swift to Objective C header file not found

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, objective-c-swift-bridge

I have this issue on the latest Xcode 8.0 where when I attempt to `#import "xxx-Swift.h"` in my Objective C implementation I get an error in my code editor of "file not found".
 The project builds and debugs fine, but I cannot seem to get rid of this annoying red bullet.
 I have been through all the build settings, and triggered and played with every single one of them.
 Yes, these settings definately seem fine.
 As I say, the project build succeed.
 But the error in the code window is really annoying. 
Eventually I fixed it with an

```
ln -s /Users/xxx/library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/yyy/Build/Intermediates/zzz.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/zzza.build/DerivedSources/zzz-Swift.h /projectSourceFolder/zzz
```

Anybody have a better suggestion on how I can fix this or what I am doing wrong?
 Perhaps, an Xcode bug? 
Feedback / suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Quit Xcode and empty the DerivedData folder.

Comment: Check the Ans of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31557345/xxx-swift-h-file-not-found-in-test-project

Answer (score 0):

Go to File -> New -> File... select Swift File, name the file as Objective-C-BridgingHeader.swift (any name you want) and click create. Then it will presented with another dialog that says "**Would you like to configure an Objective-C bridging header?**" Click Yes will automatically create the "yourprojectname-Swift.h" file for you.

[image]

This is the one of the simple way to create the bridging header.