# Using Swift on Objective-C file in custom Swift framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks

I want to create a custom framework using Swift. There're some Swift files in the framework, then I create a new Objective-C file named A (A.h and A.m).

Within this Objective-C file, I want to use another Swift class so I add a following import statement on the top of the A.m file

```
#import "<My framework target name>-Swift.h"
```

When building framework, I got error that indicates  '-Swift.h' not found.

I worked around some solutions but still get stuck

- I add an bridging header file but failed due to custom framework not allows bridging header.
- I turned on 'Defines Module' to YES on Build Settings but seems useless.
- Adding '$(CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR)/Product Name With Spaces.build/DerivedSources' to Header Search Path doesn't help.(following this thread [iOS - 'MyProject-Swift.h' file not found when running Unit Tests for Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26473058/ios-myproject-swift-h-file-not-found-when-running-unit-tests-for-swift) , @gagarwal 's answer)
- I also tried to move the import statement to umbrella header, but the same error occurs.

How can I use Swift class in the Objective-C file?

Answer (score 0):

The format of your #import statement is how you include the bridging header in an Objective-C file in an application target.

In an Objective-C file inside a framework target, to import the Swift interface your import statement needs to look like this:

```
#import <FrameworkProductName/FrameworkProductModuleName-Swift.h>
```

Also, remember that in a framework target, you have to make classes and properties you want to accessible from Swift *public* or *open*, in addition to @objc where necessary.