# How to make protocol from Swift visible in .h file?

Tags: objective-c, swift, protocols

I have a 3 files:

PLThreadViewController.swift

```
@objc protocol PLThreadViewDelegate {
    func threadViewControlledWillDismiss(threadViewController: PLThreadViewController)
}

class PLThreadViewController: UIViewController {}
```

PLMessagesTableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PLMessagesTableViewController : UITableViewController <PLThreadViewDelegate>

@end
```

The problem is: **Cannot find the protocol declaration for PLThreadViewDelegate**

When i try to add:

```
#import "Module-Swift.h"
```

then:

**Module-Swift.h file not found**. The name of module is very correct. I read about spaces, underscores in the name and so on.

Comment: Did you try cleaning? (shift command K)

Comment: Yes, I did, but it still missing `"Module-Swift.h"` file

Comment: i had similar issue and found solution at this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28484941/12147938

Answer (score 0):

Did Xcode create a bridging header for you? If so, look at the naming Xcode uses there and that will clue you in on how your "-Swift.h" file is named. So if your bridging header is named My_Project-Bridging-Header.h, your auto-generated Swift header will be My_Project-Swift.h.

Comment: yes, it did. The name of file is good. It works in other places vey well.

Comment: Check target membership of the file that can't see the protocol, as well as the file with the protocol.

Comment: Select the file(s) you want to verify in the Project Navigator (left-hand pane) and then show the File Inspector (right-hand pane) to verify Target membership. This image should help: [Check membership](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17455146/Check%20target%20membership.png)

Comment: But the problem is that my file is not .swift, but  .h instead. In my case that target membership checkbox is not clickable as every checkbox in .h file

Comment: You have to check the .m file's target membership. For some reason the .h file isn't what you check.