# Cycle inside ; building could produce unreliable results: Xcode Error

Tags: ios, xcode, compile-time, build-system

I am trying to move to the new build system when compiling with Xcode. However, it gives the following error:

```
Cycle details:
→ Target 'project' : LinkStoryboards

Target 'project' has compile command with input '/Users/project/Commons/Components/ScreenshotSharing/ViewController/AppShare.storyboard'

Target 'project' : ValidateEmbeddedBinary /Users/project/Xcode/DerivedData/project-hgqvaddkhmzxfkaycbicisabeakv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/project.app/PlugIns/stickers.appex

Target 'project' has process command with input '/Users/project/Resources/Info.plist'

Target 'project' has compile command with input '/Users/project/Commons/Components/ScreenshotSharing/ViewController/AppShare.storyboard'
```

[image: Screenshot added]

Even after removing the problem file, I get the same for another xib/storyboard. How can I solve this error without reverting to the legacy build system?

Comment: I had similar error and got it fixed by deleting 'derived data' and cleaning project. This worked like a charm to me!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was finally able to resolve this by moving `Embed App Extensions` script in `Build Phases` of main Target to last position.

Comment: Got this error in Xcode 10.0 beta 4 (10L213o) – this workaround solved it :-)

Comment: how to do that ? can you explain it step by step ?, basically, I have a extension for Siri kit in it and can not run application on simulator but it work on the device

Answer (score 66):

In fact, you only need to pay attention to Xcode's prompt `This usually can be resolved by moving the target's Headers build phase before Compile Sources`, and then you can do it.

When I encountered this problem, Xcode prompts me:

```rb
:-1: Cycle inside XXXX; building could produce unreliable results. This usually can be resolved by moving the target's Headers build phase before Compile Sources.
Cycle details:
→ Target 'XXXX': LinkStoryboards
○ Target 'XXXX: Ditto Path/XXXX-Swift.h /Path/XXXX-Swift.h
○ Target 'XXXX has compile command for Swift source files
○ That command depends on command in Target 'XXXX: script phase “Run Script”
```

I only did one thing and solved the problem perfectly:

Select `Target` and then select `Build Phase` to move the `Run Script` to the front of `Compile Sources`.

Run, compiled successfully.

The principle is simple, just change the compilation order.

[image: image 1]

Xcode 10.2 &
Swift 5

Comment: this works but only once and then in the next build command, the issue comes back.

Comment: Thanks, that works for me. I used R.swift and this step was in "Installation" but i missed it.

Comment: Just move the "Run Script" at the bottom of the list.

Answer (score 54):

I was having this issue with Cocoapods.  The solution was to clean the build folder re-install all pods, and then rebuild the app.  The issue resolved itself that way.

Comment: This worked for me as well. I did a clean and a pod install.

Comment: In my case, I'd just done a pod install so only had to clean the build folder. This error only came up after I allowed Xcode to update build settings.

Comment: had the issue with Alamofire.  Did a 'Clean Build Folder' without reinstalling any cocoa pods and worked fine

Comment: How do you clean the build folder?

Answer (score 54):

For anybody having an issue with Xcode 10 build system, follow the following steps to fix it:

> 1. In Xcode, go to File->Project/Workspace settings.
> 2. Change the build system to Legacy Build system.

It will resolve the build issue with the new Xcode.

If you want to work with the new build system, then you can find the troubleshooting help [from this apple Xcode help page](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev621201fb0).

Comment: The whole point of the question is to move to the latest build system.

Comment: Then you should mention that in question that you don’t want solution with changing the build system. Also, I have mentioned that if you want to work with new build system then you can follow steps given at Xcode support center. Also, provide a valid reason when you downvote. Thanks! @SahilKapoor

Comment: Thank you kind stranger. My only interest is getting my build working again to hit a deadline so your answer is exactly what I needed.

Comment: This is not an appropriate solution to the problem. The build system should not be changed to Legacy for something this simple.

Comment: Do NOT follow these instructions. This is incorrect. There's a hint in the name: "Legacy" - in fact, it's been deprecated and no longer supported going forward.

Answer (score 41):

Same problem on **Xcode 15**

**Solution 1**

> If there is a **run script** inside a **build phase** then put it down (dragged to the bottom)

[Where is the run script? Check here for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39633955/11762907)

**Solution 2**

Xcode 15 does not support iOS 11.0 and below. The supported deployment target version limit for this platform is 12.0.

Add the following block at the end of the podfile

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY'] = 'No'
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
      __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
    end
  end
end
```

**Solution 3** (it worked for me)

**Check the Copy only when installed** inside the build phase in Embed Foundation Extensions

[image]

[take a look here also](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/730974)

Comment: your third solution worked for me. I was trying to use share extension with flutter app

Comment: Ok upvote me if my solution is worked

Comment: Thanks so much, I (have to) use OneSignal and encountered the same problem. Solution 3 worked for me, too.

Comment: The first solution works in Xcode 15.0 (15A240d)

Comment: 3rd one worked for me as well. Can't imagine that can be the solution. Thank you
Xcode 15

Comment: I cannot thank you enough. The problem showed up on **Xcode 15** and your **1st solution** worked for me. I had to move all build phases with a script bellow my `Embed Foundation Extensions` section for the error to go away.

Comment: The third one worked for me (Xcode 15 brought it).
But in my case, the name of the build phase was Embed Watch Content because my app has a watch companion app.

Comment: 3rd solution worked,
everything was fine before upgrading Xcode to xcode 15.
Thanks mate

Comment: Solution 3 worked for me, however the problem persists when trying to archive a build.

Comment: I just tried Solution 3 and it worked ✅. Definitely, the right solution for me was Solution 3. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 34):

I fixed my problem by moving the 'Copy Bundle Resources' Build Phase before all my 'Copy Files' & 'Link Binary with Libraries' Build Phases

Comment: +1 but I used a slight variation.  I did not need to move anything ahead of "Link Binary with Libraries", which I would not do because a new default project in Xcode is not like that.  I just moved "Copy Bundle Resources" ahead of "Copy Helper Tools" (which copies some command-line tools and a helper app to Contents/Helpers of the macOS app product).  But since the order of these two should make any difference – they are only copying files – it does not make sense.  So I filed a bug: 42927301.  My modified solution: Swap around various Copy XXX Build Phases until it works :(

Comment: Same for me, I moved my Copy Bundle Resources above the Copy Files phase and presto it works now.  I will dupe your bug @JerryKrinock

Comment: For me, the problem was with Embed Frameworks dependencies, so I moved Embed Frameworks above Copy Bundle Resources, and it helped.

Answer (score 25):

I was having this issue with Cocoapods and found a temporary workaround:

1. Install latest version of cocoapods (1.5.3): `sudo gem update cocoapods`
2. Delete you derived data: `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*`
3. `pod install`

Source [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7833) and I'm on Xcode 10 beta 4.

**EDIT**: now on Xcode 10.0 and still relevant.

Comment: it happened to me again last week on Xcode 10.1 (10B61) and it still worked.
Make sure to perform a `Clean Build Folder` (and quitting Xcode might help also) before doing steps `2.` and `3.`.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 19):

Xcode 10's new build system detects dependency cycles in your build and provides diagnostics to help you resolve them. Fixing these dependency cycles improves the reliability of your build, so that the correct products are produced consistently (cycles are a possible cause of needing to delete your derived data). It also improves your incremental build times, as cycles in the build cause something in your build graph to always be out-of-date on each build, making the build re-do work unnecessarily every time you build.

There is documentation on resolving some common types of dependency cycles in Xcode Help: https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev621201fb0

That said, this cycle diagnostic looks a little odd. It sounds like you were able to resolve it by re-arranging your build phases, but I don't think the diagnostic really explained the problem. If you wouldn't mind, a bug report about improving this diagnostic for this particular case would be very much appreciated. You can file one at https://bugreport.apple.com. Please include all details about your project that you think might be relevant; a sample project that reproduces the issue is ideal, but if you can't attach that, the diagnostic and some idea of the project structure is still helpful.

Answer (score 18):

This is an the issue on `Xcode15` beta 8, for those using `Firebase Crashlytics`. Fix is to move Crashlytics run script phase(or maybe some other script phase for you) to the bottom of the `Build Phases` tab.

Edit: issue persists on Xcode15 RC.

Comment: This worked, somehow! How did you manage to find out that this was the cause?

Comment: I have found it somewhere on Apple's forum I think.

Comment: This solved it for me. Currently using Xcode 15.0.1.

Answer (score 17):

I had a similar issue with a mixed interaction between **Swift, Objective-C and CoreData**: in my project (written in Swift) I made use of Core Data's autogenerated Swift classes as well.

But at one point I needed an Objective C class with public properties (defined in its header counterpart) referring the the core data entities.

```
#import "ProjectName-Swift.h" // this is to import the swift entities into ObjC

@interface myObjCClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) MyCoreDataClass*myEntity;

@end
```

As soon as I changed the CoreData model, XCode tried to rebuild the classes and I got hung with the indicated cycle build error.

After an initial moment of despair, as I did not have any compile header phases in my project to change the order of, I found out that solution was quite simple:

In the `myObjCClass.h` I removed the shared Swift header import statement and changed it with a `@class` directive:

```
@class MyCoreDataClass; // tell the compiler I will import the class definition somewhere else

// the rest stays the same
@interface myObjCClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) MyCoreDataClass*myEntity;

@end
```

and I moved the `#import "ProjectName-Swift.h"` statement into the `myObjCClass.m` class definition file.

```
#import "myObjCClass.h"
#import "ProjectName-Swift.h"

@implementation myObjCClass

@end
```

And it builded no worries.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much. Been struggling all night with this, but when I thoroughly implemented this suggestion, the problem was fixed!

Answer (score 11):

Solution that worked for me --> go to Build Phase and move Embed Foundation Extensions up to just below Copy Bundle Resources.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

My solution was simply to Clean Build Folder then re-build.

Comment: Amazing how nobody rated on this solution. Simple but it's gotta be the first thing we should try before going deeper into the issue.

Comment: Yep, this fixed it for me

Comment: This worked for me - I'm currently on Xcode 13 and 'Clean Build Folder' can be found under the main 'Product' menu option.

Comment: This is not a solution as it keeps happening.

Answer (score 7):

In the target's `Scheme`, find the label `Build`, and ensure that `Find Implicit Dependencies` is not checked. These steps may work.

Comment: This solved the problem for me, I unchecked this from the Scheme build tab for the main target (Xcode 13.3).

Comment: Followup:  With that unchecked it would not build attached Framework I had included in the project.  So then I cleaned the build folder, re-checked it... and the error message was gone.

Answer (score 7):

I was facing the same issue: below was the error

> Cycle in dependencies between targets 'Pods-MyAppName' and 'RxCocoa';
>   building could produce unreliable results. This usually can be
>   resolved by moving the target's Headers build phase before Compile
>   Sources. Cycle path: Pods-MyAppName → RxCocoa → Pods-MyAppName

I solved it using the below steps:

1). Go to target RxCocoa in Pods-MyAppName project

2) Go to build phases

3) Drag the Headers Phase and move it above the Complile Sources build phase.

This fixed my issue.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue with Cocoapods.

Firstly, remove pods:

```
rm -rf ios/Pods
```

then install pods again:

```
cd ios && pod install && cd ..
```

Then run your app, it should works now.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this issue by moving the Embed App Extensions, Embed Frameworks, and Embed Pods Frameworks to be performed before the Run Script in tab build phase.

Comment: thank you @Taif! your solution worked great. any ideas on why it worked?

Answer (score 3):

I've met similar issue when tried to archive my project on Xcode 10.
Here's the detail text:

```
→ Target 'mytarget': CodeSign /path/to/mytarget.app

○ Target 'mytarget': SetGroup staff /path/to/mytarget.app

○ Target 'mytarget': SetMode u+w,go-w,a+rX /path/to/mytarget.app

○ Target 'mytarget': SetGroup staff /path/to/mytarget.app
```

Fixed it by setting `$(USER)` in `mytarget -> Build Settings -> Deployment -> Install Owner`

Answer (score 3):

My issue had to do with a cyclical dependency between my swift bridging header and my objective c files.

In my objective c header files I had a `#import "...-swift.h"` file and then in a couple of my swift files I was including those files with said import and thus causing a cyclical dependency.

This is the StackOverflow that led me to find the solution:

[Objective C, Swift Interoperability issue due to circular dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31510901/objective-c-swift-interoperability-issue-due-to-circular-dependency)

[How to prevent circular reference when Swift bridging header imports a file that imports Hopscotch-Swift.h itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25670431/how-to-prevent-circular-reference-when-swift-bridging-header-imports-a-file-that)

**EDIT:**

I wound up converting the above files to swift and this solved my issue.

Answer (score 3):

The best temporary fix I've found (until you resolve the root problem) is to make a simple change to the source code (even something as trivial as adding a new line) then trying again. I find that making even a whitespace change is enough to allow it to build again. However, this is definitely temporary as it will likely happen again after a few tries.

This is better than cleaning the build folder (which I found to also be temporary) since it's much quicker to make a whitespace change and rebuild, than to clean the build folder and rebuild (especially on larger projects).

Comment: It's really terrible, but this does actually work :(

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you need to change the order of the build phases within your Pods targets. For me, moving Headers above the rest worked. You can automate this in your Podfile:

```
require 'xcodeproj'

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    headers_phase = target.build_phases.find { |p| p.kind_of?(Xcodeproj::Project::Object::PBXHeadersBuildPhase) }
    if headers_phase
      puts "#{target.name}: Moving Headers build phase to top"
      target.build_phases.insert(0, target.build_phases.delete_at(target.build_phases.index(headers_phase)))
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to fix this here:

File -> Workspace Settings -> Build System: New Build System

[image: Workspace Settings]

Answer (score 2):

Fixing this problem is relatively straightforward, yet it's another one of those frustrating issues that Apple presents to its developers.

Follow these steps:

1. Navigate to the Build Phase tab.
2. Drag the 'Embed App Extension' and position it beneath the 'Run script'.

Now, run it once more.

Answer (score 2):

1 - Select Target and then select Build Phase to move the Run Script to the front of Compile Sources
[image]

2 - edite pod file find

> installer.pods_project.targets.each

and make your code as below

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
    config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
    '$(inherited)',
    'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1',
    'PERMISSION_MICROPHONE=1',
  ]
end
  end
end
```

3- File -> Workspace Settings -> Build System: New Build System

[image]

if you are in flutter run

> flutter clean

if in React-Native

> cd ios && rm -rf Pods && pod install && cd ..

regard

Comment: The first step worked for even SPM

Answer (score 1):

Same issue on `Version 10.0 beta 3 (10L201y)` and I wanted to have the *New Build System*.

Problem is had disabled `Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)`

in `Build Settings -> Apple Clang - Language - Modules`

After enabling it (set to YES) got rid of the Error.

Answer (score 1):

## Core_Data

I had the same problem and error but mine happened when I "Created NSManagedObject Subclass" for my entity and I faced this error. So if you think your error is same as mine about Core Data what can probably help you (and helped me ) is to:

- click on your Entity in you "xcdatamodel" file
- go to  your right bar click on  Data Model Inspector
- change "Module" to  "Current Product Module"
- and finally, change "Codegen" to "Manual/None"
- clean and build

I think because in other scenarios Xcode creates a file automatically and when we create another one it causes a conflict.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 10.2.1/Unit Test Target. My unit test target is independent of host target to improve building time. Solve it by uncheck `Find Implicit Dependencies` in `Scheme` -  `Build` options, As i specify all dependencies in `Build Settings` - `Compile Sources`.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode: 11.3.1
Target: XCUITest target

1. Run command to clean build folder : rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
2. Change workspace settings: Select **Legacy Build System**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have tried things from this page but the only thing that has helped me was that I made a copy of the target and updated the name of the copy (removed the copy suffix), and deleted the old one, and did pod install afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem after updating Xcode to version 11.4. Downgrading to 11.2.1 fixed it.

Comment: same here. downgrade from XCode 13.3 to 13.2 helped

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem for a while as well. Added the following block at the end of the podfile (this will also get rid of some warnings):

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.deployment_target = ios_version
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = 'iOS ' + ios_version
    end
  end
end
```

I also moved `use_frameworks!` to the root of the `Podfile`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

Removed all pods and reinstall resolved the error

```
Remove Pods directory in ios folder
pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

**Only for Expo**

1. `expo prebuild --clean`
2. `cd ios`
3. `pod install`
4. `yarn ios`

Answer (score 0):

if you are developing on React-Native, it was the best way for me.

`cd ios && rm -rf Pods && pod install && cd ..`

Answer (score 0):

I know the original question was asking about pure iOS, but if anyone is running into this issue when trying to run native code with Flutter, try the following:

1. Run `flutter clean` in terminal or from the Android Studio menus
2. Clean your build folder in XCode (Product -> Clean Build Folder)
3. Comment out every bit of native code that you've added to your main application class that references other files.
4. Comment out everything except `#import "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"` in your bridging header file (`[project name]-Bridging-Header.h` by default I think)
5. Target a simulator and run the app from XCode
6. Uncomment everything you commented out in steps 3 and 4

That's been fixing it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I used react-native Expo and I resolved this question reorder "Build Phases". My ordered list like this.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In the project pane on the LHS, for your build products, don't select them in the list for Target membership in the RHS pane.

Answer (score -3):

Following two options worked for me: File->Project/Workspace settings.

1, Change the build system to "Legacy Build system" in File->Project Settings

2, Edit Scheme and Select "Parallelize Build" option under Build section.

Comment: That's not related. Modern build system wouldn't cause this.

Answer (score -3):

1. Delete all Derived data
2. Clean the build
3. Run it on a device or simulator.