# App builds with all Xcode versions <= 14.3.1 but with Xcode 15 gets a "Cycle inside" build error

Tags: ios, xcode

My app builds fine with Xcode 14.n, 13.n, 12.n, but when attempting to build it with Xcode 15 there's a build error:

> "Cycle inside MyApp; building could produce unreliable results."

The output below isn't giving me any clues that I can see about what the cause of the cycle is nor how to fix it, any ideas?

I've tried several things suggested here but with no success: [Cycle inside ; building could produce unreliable results: Xcode Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50709330/cycle-inside-building-could-produce-unreliable-results-xcode-error)

```
Cycle inside MyApp; building could produce unreliable results.
Cycle details:
→ Target 'MyApp': ExtractAppIntentsMetadata
○ Target 'MyApp': CodeSign /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectA-frqscjhianktlvbxgbzostesljpn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/Frameworks/3rdPartyFramework.framework
○ Target 'MyApp' has copy command from '/Users/me/Desktop/Checkouts/MyApp/theApp/MyApp/ios/3rdPartyFramework.framework' to '/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectA-frqscjhianktlvbxgbzostesljpn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/Frameworks/3rdPartyFramework.framework'
○ Target 'MyApp' has copy command from '/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectA-frqscjhianktlvbxgbzostesljpn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/CallExtension.appex' to '/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectA-frqscjhianktlvbxgbzostesljpn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/PlugIns/CallExtension.appex'
○ That command depends on command in Target 'MyApp': script phase “Add Git/CI Build Info”
○ Target 'MyApp' has process command with output '/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectA-frqscjhianktlvbxgbzostesljpn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/Info.plist'
○ Target 'MyApp' has copy command from '/Users/me/Desktop/Checkouts/MyApp/theApp/MyApp/ios/3rdPartyFramework.framework' to '/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectA-frqscjhianktlvbxgbzostesljpn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/Frameworks/3rdPartyFramework.framework'


Raw dependency cycle trace:

target:  ->

node: <all> ->

command: <all> ->

node: /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectA-frqscjhianktlvbxgbzostesljpn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ProjectA.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ExtractedAppShortcutsMetadata.stringsdata ->

command: P0:target-MyApp-2a7e5ca2b3fd2ca0faca1487721e3ae07ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6-:Debug:ExtractAppIntentsMetadata ->

node: <target-MyApp-2a7e5ca2b3fd2ca0faca1487721e3ae07ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6--package-copy-files-phase> ->

command: P0:::Gate target-MyApp-2a7e5ca2b3fd2ca0faca1487721e3ae07ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6--package-copy-files-phase ->

node: <target-MyApp-2a7e5ca2b3fd2ca0faca1487721e3ae07ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6--fused-phase11-copy-files> ->

command: P0:::Gate target-MyApp-2a7e5ca2b3fd2ca0faca1487721e3ae07ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6--fused-phase11-copy-files ->

node: <CodeSign /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectA-frqscjhianktlvbxgbzostesljpn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/Frameworks/3rdPartyFramework.framework> ->

command: P0:target-MyApp-2a7e5ca2b3fd2ca0faca1487721e3ae07ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6-:Debug:CodeSign /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectA-frqscjhianktlvbxgbzostesljpn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/Frameworks/3rdPartyFramework.framework ->

node: <Copy /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectA-frqscjhianktlvbxgbzostesljpn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/Frameworks/3rdPartyFramework.framework> ->

CYCLE POINT ->

command: P0:target-MyApp-2a7e5ca2b3fd2ca0faca1487721e3ae07ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6-:Debug:Copy /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectA-frqscjhianktlvbxgbzostesljpn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/Frameworks/3rdPartyFramework.framework /Users/me/Desktop/Checkouts/MyApp/theApp/MyApp/ios/3rdPartyFramework.framework ->

node: <target-MyApp-2a7e5ca2b3fd2ca0faca1487721e3ae07ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6--fused-phase10--cp--copy-pods-resources> ->

command: P0:::Gate target-MyApp-2a7e5ca2b3fd2ca0faca1487721e3ae07ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6--fused-phase10--cp--copy-pods-resources ->

node: /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectA-frqscjhianktlvbxgbzostesljpn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ProjectA.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.build/InputFileList-F72A917A68CD9152103DBA60-Pods-MyApp-resources-Debug-input-files-037b34732b45cb31a2dcb00ffdfe9f5c-resolved.xcfilelist ->

command: P2:target-MyApp-2a7e5ca2b3fd2ca0faca1487721e3ae07ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6-:Debug:WriteAuxiliaryFile /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectA-frqscjhianktlvbxgbzostesljpn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ProjectA.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.build/InputFileList-F72A917A68CD9152103DBA60-Pods-MyApp-resources-Debug-input-files-037b34732b45cb31a2dcb00ffdfe9f5c-resolved.xcfilelist ->

node: <target-MyApp-2a7e5ca2b3fd2ca0faca1487721e3ae07ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6--fused-phase9--cp--embed-pods-frameworks> ->

command: P0:::Gate target-MyApp-2a7e5ca2b3fd2ca0faca1487721e3ae07ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6--fused-phase9--cp--embed-pods-frameworks ->

node: /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectA-frqscjhianktlvbxgbzostesljpn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ProjectA.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.build/InputFileList-7E0D6830477C665FCC1083CC-Pods-MyApp-frameworks-Debug-input-files-36820974ee8465975a73448c9644b936-resolved.xcfilelist ->

command: P2:target-MyApp-2a7e5ca2b3fd2ca0faca1487721e3ae07ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6-:Debug:WriteAuxiliaryFile /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectA-frqscjhianktlvbxgbzostesljpn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ProjectA.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.build/InputFileList-7E0D6830477C665FCC1083CC-Pods-MyApp-frameworks-Debug-input-files-36820974ee8465975a73448c9644b936-resolved.xcfilelist ->

node: <target-MyApp-2a7e5ca2b3fd2ca0faca1487721e3ae07ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6--fused-phase8-upload-crashlytics> ->

command: P0:::Gate target-MyApp-2a7e5ca2b3fd2ca0faca1487721e3ae07ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6--fused-phase8-upload-crashlytics ->

node: <target-MyApp-2a7e5ca2b3fd2ca0faca1487721e3ae07ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6--fused-phase7-upload-debug-symbols-to-sentry> ->

command: P0:::Gate target-MyApp-2a7e5ca2b3fd2ca0faca1487721e3ae07ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6--fused-phase7-upload-debug-symbols-to-sentry ->

node: <target-MyApp-2a7e5ca2b3fd2ca0faca1487721e3ae07ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6--fused-phase6-crashlytics> ->

command: P0:::Gate target-MyApp-2a7e5ca2b3fd2ca0faca1487721e3ae07ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6--fused-phase6-crashlytics ->

node: <target-MyApp-2a7e5ca2b3fd2ca0faca1487721e3ae07ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6--fused-phase5-copy-files> ->

command: P0:::Gate target-MyApp-2a7e5ca2b3fd2ca0faca1487721e3ae07ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6--fused-phase5-copy-files ->

node: <Copy /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectA-frqscjhianktlvbxgbzostesljpn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/PlugIns/CallExtension.appex> ->

command: P0:target-MyApp-2a7e5ca2b3fd2ca0faca1487721e3ae07ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6-:Debug:Copy /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectA-frqscjhianktlvbxgbzostesljpn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/PlugIns/CallExtension.appex /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectA-frqscjhianktlvbxgbzostesljpn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/CallExtension.appex ->

node: <target-MyApp-2a7e5ca2b3fd2ca0faca1487721e3ae07ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6--fused-phase4-bundle-react-native-code-and-images> ->

command: P0:::Gate target-MyApp-2a7e5ca2b3fd2ca0faca1487721e3ae07ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6--fused-phase4-bundle-react-native-code-and-images ->

node: /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectA-frqscjhianktlvbxgbzostesljpn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ProjectA.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh ->

command: P2:target-MyApp-2a7e5ca2b3fd2ca0faca1487721e3ae07ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6-:Debug:WriteAuxiliaryFile /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectA-frqscjhianktlvbxgbzostesljpn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ProjectA.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh ->

node: <target-MyApp-2a7e5ca2b3fd2ca0faca1487721e3ae07ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6--fused-phase3-add-git-ci-build-info> ->

command: P0:::Gate target-MyApp-2a7e5ca2b3fd2ca0faca1487721e3ae07ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6--fused-phase3-add-git-ci-build-info ->

node: <execute-shell-script-2a7e5ca2b3fd2ca0faca1487721e3ae004c462d93c7eb2257aed820e07a8e286-target-MyApp-2a7e5ca2b3fd2ca0faca1487721e3ae07ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6-> ->

command: P2:target-MyApp-2a7e5ca2b3fd2ca0faca1487721e3ae07ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6-:Debug:PhaseScriptExecution Add Git/CI Build Info /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectA-frqscjhianktlvbxgbzostesljpn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ProjectA.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Script-F64F322E29D3670D0018FC3B.sh ->

node: /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectA-frqscjhianktlvbxgbzostesljpn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/Info.plist/ ->

directoryTreeSignature: � ->

directoryContents: /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectA-frqscjhianktlvbxgbzostesljpn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/Info.plist ->

node: /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectA-frqscjhianktlvbxgbzostesljpn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/Info.plist ->

command: P0:target-MyApp-2a7e5ca2b3fd2ca0faca1487721e3ae07ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6-:Debug:ProcessInfoPlistFile /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectA-frqscjhianktlvbxgbzostesljpn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/Info.plist /Users/me/Desktop/Checkouts/MyApp/theApp/MyApp/ios/MyApp/CeqInfo.plist ->

node: /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectA-frqscjhianktlvbxgbzostesljpn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/Frameworks/3rdPartyFramework.framework ->

command: P0:target-MyApp-2a7e5ca2b3fd2ca0faca1487721e3ae07ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6-:Debug:Copy /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectA-frqscjhianktlvbxgbzostesljpn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/Frameworks/3rdPartyFramework.framework /Users/me/Desktop/Checkouts/MyApp/theApp/MyApp/ios/3rdPartyFramework.framework
```

Build phases:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: if you don't *need* your Info.plist to be listed as an "Input File" to your Run Script build phase, remove it. That resolved the problem for me.

---

I had nearly exactly the same problem. For me, the Run Script build phase that was causing the problem (for you it's "Add Git/CI Build Info") had two items defined as "Input Files". One of them was `$(SRCROOT)/$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)`.

Apparently that makes it dependent on a compilation step called "ProcessInfoPlistFile" - you can see on lines 100–102 of your pasted text, the node `...Info.plist` has a dependency on the command `...ProcessInfoPlistFile`. And you can see on the following line (104) that `ProcessInfoPlistFile` has a dependency on the node `...3rdPartyFramework.framework`. (I have no idea why this is the case.) (I may have the directions of the dependencies inverted...I find this log output super difficult to understand.)

So that's why there's a cyclical dependency. `ExtractAppIntentsMetadata` eventually requires `3rdPartyFramework.framework` to be copied into your app, which requires your Info.plist to be processed, which requires `3rdPartyFramework.framework` to be copied into your app.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to look at this. You were right - I completely deleted the Add Git/CI Build Into step and it built. Now to try putting it back and figuring out why there's something going on between ProcessInfoPlistFile and 3rdPartyFramework, or why Xcode thinks there is.