# Cycle inside <Target>; building could produce unreliable results. Xcode 15 React Native

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, expo, xcode15

I was using `"react-native": "0.72.3"` with Xcode 14, and everything was working perfectly but when I updated Xcode to **Xcode 15**. then it is giving error like below

Note: I was using Live Activity and Dynamic Island widget extension and two notification widget extensions.

```
Showing Recent Messages
Cycle inside <Target>; building could produce unreliable results.
Cycle details:
→ Target '<Target>': ExtractAppIntentsMetadata
○ Target '<Target>' has copy command from '/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<Target>-hifbytcglbabrcgbkmfgnzgmwpmj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/LiveActivityDynamicIslandExtension.appex' to '/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<Target>-hifbytcglbabrcgbkmfgnzgmwpmj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/<Target>.app/PlugIns/LiveActivityDynamicIslandExtension.appex'
○ That command depends on command in Target '<Target>': script phase “[CP-User] [RNFB] Core Configuration”
○ Target '<Target>' has process command with output '/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<Target>-hifbytcglbabrcgbkmfgnzgmwpmj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/<Target>.app/Info.plist'
○ Target '<Target>' has copy command from '/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<Target>-hifbytcglbabrcgbkmfgnzgmwpmj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/LiveActivityDynamicIslandExtension.appex' to '/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<Target>-hifbytcglbabrcgbkmfgnzgmwpmj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/<Target>.app/PlugIns/LiveActivityDynamicIslandExtension.appex'
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cycle inside ; building could produce unreliable results: Xcode Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50709330/cycle-inside-building-could-produce-unreliable-results-xcode-error)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Firebase packages then you can try **Firebase** solutions otherwise you can try **Other Solutions**

## Firebase Solutions

it happens when you are using firebase pods like this in `Podfile`

```
  pod 'nanopb', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseSessions', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreExtension', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseInstallations', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleDataTransport', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCrashlytics', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'CleverTap-iOS-SDK', :modular_headers => true
```

### Solution1:

you can choose either `Manual` way or do `Patch Package` way

##### Manual:

if you wanna use `:modular_headers => true` pods then you can try this solution

1. Goto `ProjectTarget -> Build Phases`
2. Expand `[RNFB] Core Configuration`
3. replace Input Files with `$(SRCROOT)/$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)` from `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)`

[image]
4. Go to `[CP_user][RNFB] Crashlytics Configuration` BuildPhase and Expland it

5. remove `${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}/Contents/Resources/DWARF/${TARGET_NAME}` as Input Files
   [image]
6. Run Build

##### Package patch

1. install [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package)
2. Apply two patches like below

`@react-native-firebase+app+18.3.0.patch`

```
diff --git a/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/react-native.config.js b/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/react-native.config.js
index 8502984..de75804 100644
--- a/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/react-native.config.js
+++ b/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/react-native.config.js
@@ -10,7 +10,7 @@ module.exports = {
             name: '[RNFB] Core Configuration',
             path: './ios_config.sh',
             execution_position: 'after_compile',
-            input_files: ['$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)'],
+            input_files: ['$(SRCROOT)/$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)'],
           },
         ],
       },
```

`@react-native-firebase+crashlytics+18.3.0.patch`

```
diff --git a/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/crashlytics/react-native.config.js b/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/crashlytics/react-native.config.js
index 5f6c5f1..0fc785f 100644
--- a/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/crashlytics/react-native.config.js
+++ b/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/crashlytics/react-native.config.js
@@ -24,7 +24,6 @@ module.exports = {
             path: './ios_config.sh',
             execution_position: 'after_compile',
             input_files: [
-              '${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}/Contents/Resources/DWARF/${TARGET_NAME}',
               '$(SRCROOT)/$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)',
             ],
           },
```

1. install pod by `pod install` command
2. Run Build.

### Solution 2

if you dont wanna use `:modular_headers => true` then

1. enable this `'use_frameworks! :linkage => :static'` line into your Podfile
2. run `pod install` command into your terminal
3. Run Build

## Other Solutions

### Solution 1:

In build phases, move the `Embed Frameworks` build phase above the `Run script`. run build.

[image]

### Solution 2:

In build phases, move the `Run Script` build phase to the end of the list. run build.
[image]

### Solution 3:

In build phases, move "Embed Foundation Extensions" build phase above the "[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks". run build.

[image]

### Solution 4:

1. In Xcode, go to `File -> Workspace Settings`
2. Click on `Advanced` button
3. Select the `Legacy` radio button
4. run build

Comment: Your third solution worked for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Solution 2 works for me

Comment: The second solution worked for me. Thank You