# How to mix Swift and Objective-C in a pod lib?

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods, swift2

I have created a new swift lib pod using the command : pod lib create MixSwiftObjectiveC found from https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/using-pod-lib-create.html

In this pod lib I need to use a code that's written in Objective-C.
If I would have a separate "normal" project I would just include the import in the header file …-Bridging-Header.h. 
Is there an equivalent for a pod lib? Can Swift and Objective-C be mixed inside a pod lib?

As an example I've created this github: https://github.com/crarau/MixSwiftObjectiveC
In order to run the example you'll need XCode Version 7.0 beta 6 and Swift 2.0

[image: Compilation issue]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just came across this question, any updates now?

Comment: Unfortunately, I had to go the route of not mixing the two languages in the Pod Lib.

Comment: So sad... I have a private pod lib written in objc that is large enough to be impossible to rewrite in Swift all at once. I'll also have to go with objc for now.

Answer (score 9):

This is actually pretty straight forward in cocoapod. you just need to define these lines in the .podspec file.

```
s.source_files = '{YOUR_POD}/Classes/**/*.{swift,h,m}'
s.public_header_files = '{YOUR_POD}/Classes/**/*.h'
```

"s.public_header_files" automatically create an umbrella header that serves the purpose of the bridging header as well. That's it you should be able to use ObjC classes inside swift classes.

You can also use swift classes in ObjC. you just need to import -swift header in your ObjC file.

```
#import <YOUR_POD/YOUR_POD-Swift.h>
```

As long as the dependency is one way, you would not face any issues.

Comment: Notice that you can't include swift headers in the regular headers this way, but you can do it in your implementation files. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28484941/674557

Answer (score 3):

In your `.podspec` you should have something like:

**`s.source_files = 'MixSwiftObjectiveC/Classes/*'`**

- Go to the `MixSwiftObjectiveC/Classes/` directory folder in the finder to be sure and put your files (objc and swift)
- Clean Build Folder
- navigate to your `Example..` folder and do a `pod install` (as you should have a `Podfile` under your `Example..` folder that has your `MixSwiftObjectiveC` pod)
- build and you shouldn't have anymore the issue