# Expose Objective-C Framework to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm writing a Cocoa Touch Static Library in Objective-C. It will be distributed through Cocoapods and the developers using it should also be able to do this in Swift.
In my test projects the library can be used perfectly in Objective-C, but in Swift I get the compiler error: `No such module MyLibrary`.

In the Library Target `Defines Module` is set to `YES`. According to the Apple guide here, that's the only thing one must do: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: Did you add the .pch file who include your main framework header ?

Comment: No, should that solve this problem? Do you have any link/documentation regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

To implement pch file in existing swift project:

> File > New > File... (macOS app for your case)

[image: add pch file]

then you can import your Objective-C library like this in your pch file (test.pch is my file)

```
#ifndef test_pch
#define test_pch

#import <YourLib/YourLibMainClass.h>

// Include any system framework and library headers here that should be included in all compilation units.
// You will also need to set the Prefix Header build setting of one or more of your targets to reference this file.

#endif /* test_pch */
```

Now you need to tell your project there is a pch file.
Go to your target build setting and make a search for "Prefix Header".

At *Apple LLVM 8.0 - Language* section add value for *Prefix header* key (be careful with your pch file project path)

[image]

You will could import your library on a swift file

```
import YouLibrary
```

Comment: Ok, now I understand what you mean, but that wasn't my question.
I'm writing a framework. I don't want to tell everybody who is using it to create a .pch File.

Comment: @melbic - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32459678/how-to-mix-swift-and-objective-c-in-a-pod-lib